# Display number with leading zeros

Tags: python, integer, string-formatting

How do I display a leading zero for all numbers with less than two digits?

```
1    →  01
10   →  10
100  →  100
```

Answer (score 1882, accepted):

In Python 2 (and Python 3) you can do:

```
number = 1
print("%02d" % (number,))
```

Basically **%** is like `printf` or `sprintf` (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)).

---

For Python 3.+, the same behavior can also be achieved with [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
number = 1
print("{:02d}".format(number))
```

---

For Python 3.6+ the same behavior can be achieved with [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
number = 1
print(f"{number:02d}")
```

Comment: Example: print "%05d" % result['postalCode'] for a 5 digit postal code.

Comment: `x = "%02d.txt" % i` raises TypeError (cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects), but `x = "%02d.txt" % (i,)` does not. Interesting. I wonder where is that documented

Comment: @theta In 2.7.6, I don't get an error.  Maybe this was a bug in a specific version of Python that they've since fixed?

Comment: Maybe. In 2.7.6 there is no exception if format value isn't tuple (at least for this example). Looking at the date of my comment I guess I was running 2.7.3 back then, and at that time I didn't know that putting single variable in a tuple gets you on a safe side while using `%` string formater.

Comment: To elaborate, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) explain this here: "When no explicit alignment is given, preceding the width field by a zero ('0') character enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a fill character of '0' with an alignment type of '='."

Comment: What if I want the `2` in `:02` to be a variable?

Comment: @Apollys This may be better suited to Datageek's answer below.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3371180/3421

Comment: The second example also works in [python2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve that for float numbers? I mean what should the formatting string look like for `foo = 3.95` to print `foo`'s value as `003.950`? I know how to set precision for fractional part, but what about integer part?

Answer (score 1221):

You can use [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```
print(str(1).zfill(2))
print(str(10).zfill(2))
print(str(100).zfill(2))
```

prints:

```
01
10
100
```

Comment: I like this solution, as it helps not only when outputting the number, but when you need to assign it to a variable... e.g. x = str(datetime.date.today().month).zfill(2) will return x as '02' for the month of feb.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, since the `"{1:02d}"` cannot have variables in place of `2` (like if you are creating a dynamic function).

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese It can have variables: `"{0:0{1}}"`. Pass any number of zeros you want as the second argument.

Comment: This method also works well for prepending zeroes to floating point numbers.

Answer (score 385):

In Python 2.6+ and 3.0+, you would use the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) string method:

```
for i in (1, 10, 100):
    print('{num:02d}'.format(num=i))
```

or using the built-in (for a single number):

```
print(format(i, '02d'))
```

See the [PEP-3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101) documentation for the new formatting functions.

Comment: Works in Python 2.7.5 as well. You can also use '{:02d}'.format(1) if you don't want to use named arguments.

Comment: Works fine in 2.7.2, with a floating point "{0:04.0f}".format(1.1) gives 0001 (:04 = at least 4 characters, in this case leading 0's, .0f = floating point with no decimals). I am aware of the % formatting but wanted to modify an existing .format statement without rewriting the *whole* thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 158):

```
print('{:02}'.format(1))
print('{:02}'.format(10))
print('{:02}'.format(100))
```

prints:

```
01
10
100
```

Comment: This way let you repeat the argument several times within the string: `One zero:{0:02}, two zeros: {0:03}, ninezeros: {0:010}'.format(6)`

Comment: Only compatible with Python 3. If using Python 2.7, do `print '{:02}'.format(1)`

Answer (score 118):

In **Python >= 3.6**, you can do this succinctly with the new f-strings that were introduced by using:

```
f'{val:02}'
```

which prints the variable with name `val` with a [`fill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-fill) value of `0` and a [`width`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-width) of `2`.

For your specific example you can do this nicely in a loop:

```
a, b, c = 1, 10, 100
for val in [a, b, c]:
    print(f'{val:02}')
```

which prints:

```
01 
10
100
```

---

For more information on f-strings, take a look at [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) where they were introduced.

Answer (score 93):

Or this:

`print '{0:02d}'.format(1)`

Answer (score 73):

```
x = [1, 10, 100]
for i in x:
    print '%02d' % i
```

results in:

```
01
10
100
```

Read [more information about string formatting using %](https://pyformat.info/) in the documentation.

Comment: The documentation example sucks. They throw mapping in with the leading zero sample, so it's hard to know which is which unless you already know how it works. Thats what brought me here, actually.

Answer (score 60):

The Pythonic way to do this:

```
str(number).rjust(string_width, fill_char)
```

This way, the original string is returned unchanged if its length is greater than string_width. Example:

```
a = [1, 10, 100]
for num in a:
    print str(num).rjust(2, '0')
```

Results:

```
01
10
100
```

Answer (score 35):

Or another solution.

```
"{:0>2}".format(number)
```

Comment: This would be the Python way, although I would include the parameter for clarity - `"{0:0>2}".format(number)`, if someone will wants nLeadingZeros they should note they can also do:`"{0:0>{1}}".format(number, nLeadingZeros + 1)`

Answer (score 15):

Its built into python with string formatting

```
f'{number:02d}'
```

Comment: This old question doesn't need any more answers. Your answer is also a duplicate of the accepted answer without any additional information.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this with *f strings*.

```
import numpy as np

print(f'{np.random.choice([1, 124, 13566]):0>8}')
```

This will print constant length of 8, and pad the rest with leading `0`.

```
00000001
00000124
00013566
```

Answer (score 8):

This is how I do it:

```
str(1).zfill(len(str(total)))
```

Basically zfill takes the number of leading zeros you want to add, so it's easy to take the biggest number, turn it into a string and get the length, like this:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, May 11 2018, 04:00:52) 
[GCC 8.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> total = 100
>>> print(str(1).zfill(len(str(total))))
001
>>> total = 1000
>>> print(str(1).zfill(len(str(total))))
0001
>>> total = 10000
>>> print(str(1).zfill(len(str(total))))
00001
>>>
```

Comment: Doesn't this contradict [Datageek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)?

Comment: _"zfill takes the number of leading zeros you want to add"_ This isn't correct. It adds leading zero's until the string as a whole has the desired length. E.g. `"10".zfill(2)` doesn't add any zeros.

Answer (score 5):

Use a format string - http://docs.python.org/lib/typesseq-strings.html

For example:

```
python -c 'print "%(num)02d" % {"num":5}'
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also do:

```
'{:0>2}'.format(1)
```

which will return a string.

Comment: print(f'{VALUE:0>5})' works fine too.

Answer (score 4):

```
width = 5
num = 3
formatted = (width - len(str(num))) * "0" + str(num)
print formatted
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
'00'[len(str(i)):] + str(i)
```

Or with the `math` module:

```
import math
'00'[math.ceil(math.log(i, 10)):] + str(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

All of these create the string "01":

```
>python -m timeit "'{:02d}'.format(1)"
1000000 loops, best of 5: 357 nsec per loop

>python -m timeit "'{0:0{1}d}'.format(1,2)"
500000 loops, best of 5: 607 nsec per loop

>python -m timeit "f'{1:02d}'"
1000000 loops, best of 5: 281 nsec per loop

>python -m timeit "f'{1:0{2}d}'"
500000 loops, best of 5: 423 nsec per loop

>python -m timeit "str(1).zfill(2)"
1000000 loops, best of 5: 271 nsec per loop

>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the Python way, although I would include the parameter for clarity - "{0:0>2}".format(number), if someone will wants nLeadingZeros they should note they can also do:"{0:0>{1}}".format(number, nLeadingZeros + 1)

Answer (score -2):

If dealing with numbers that are either one or two digits:

`'0'+str(number)[-2:]` or `'0{0}'.format(number)[-2:]`