# Relative Filepathing within Jupyter Imported Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a basic yet annoying file reading issue.

I have a repo set up like this:

```
/repo/functions/feature.py
               /script.sql

/repo/notebooks/task.ipynb
```

Within `feature.py`, I have a function that reads the `script.sql` and modifies it based off some input. Importing this function into a notebook within the `/functions` directory works just fine.

However, when I have a notebook `task.ipynb` in a different directory `/notebooks`, the function now gives a "File not found" error. If I move the .sql file to `/notebooks` then it works again, but this is far from ideal. I have also considered consolidating all static files into one directory, but this is annoying.

Is there a way to correctly route the file path lookup to always occur within the place it is inputted, regardless of where the function itself is imported and called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want: [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174211/how-to-make-an-always-relative-to-current-module-file-path).

You can use the `__file__` keyword within feature.py to access the directory where feature.py is. You can then build a path to script.sql reliably if it is always in the same directory as feature.py.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an answer award to spatzlsberger, as he did point me the right way to [How to make an "always relative to current module" file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174211/how-to-make-an-always-relative-to-current-module-file-path)

This answer worked out for me. Leverage pathlib and modify the filepaths like so.

```
from pathlib import Path

here = Path(__file__).parent
fname = here/'script.sql'
```