# How does python find modules without a specifying path?

Tags: python, django

For example, when using django I can get my settings from anywhere within the project using `from djanog.conf import settings`. I don't have to specify where `django.conf` is, it just knows. How does it know?

I ask because I'm building a project where I need to be able to import a `conf` file without knowing the relative path. Right now I have to figure out the relative path to the `conf` file each time I use it. I would prefer to just do something like `from config import settings`. I figure I need to add my `conf` file to `sys.path` but I'm not sure where to do this. Is there a standard way for handling this type of problem in python?

I'm sure some variation of this question has been asked hundreds of times before but I can't seem to find the answer. If you know of a good answer that already exists please let me knows. Thanks.

Comment: Python uses [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) to determine the default search path for modules. However, please elaborate on your "need to be able to import a conf file without knowing the relative path", please?

Comment: Tried to elaborate a bit more. Not completely sure how to elaborate more.

Comment: You should probably look at what `django.conf.settings` does - it's basically a proxy for the user settings module specified by an environment variable.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking `conf` is a file extension, part of the file `django.conf`? That is incorrect, `conf` is a Python module that’s part of the `django` package. As such it is `django` that is found on `sys.path`, and `conf` and `settings` are found by traversing the `django/` directory contents.

Comment: There are too many possibilities for what you are actually trying to do. If you need to find a file relative to your code, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174211/how-to-make-an-always-relative-to-current-module-file-path

Answer (score 1):

Well the reason that `from django.conf import settings` works is that django.conf is just a sub package of the django python package and not a .conf file. So when you do `from django.conf import settings` the same magic that makes `import django` work. It is just the [standard python import mechanism](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

The settings object you get by doing `from django.conf import settings` is  [this python object](https://github.com/django/django/blob/213850b4b9641bdcb714172999725ec9aa9c9e84/django/conf/__init__.py#L238). So you could just try to see what `LazySettings()` does. The way django actually reads your settings (and not just the global default settings) is by reading the location of the settings file through from environment variable by doing `os.environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE")`, and being able to locate the location of the user specified settings file through an environment variable is a good standard practice.

However this does not solve the problem of having a `default.conf` file somewhere in your project if a user does not specify its own settings file through an environment variable.

For example if you have `settings.py` and `default.conf` in the same directory you could do something like

```
import pathlib
  
DEFAULT_CONF_FILE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("default.conf").absolute()
```

in `settings.py` and then if you need to have the location of `default.conf` anywhere you can just import `DEFAULT_CONF_FILE` from `settings.py`