# Running and Reading from directories with Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, import, directory, read-write

I am trying to import test.py from within main.py how would I be able to do that? Both `main.py` and `test.py` and the `data.json` is allocated within the application folder. The `test.py` file is within the app folder. I am trying to open and read the `data.json` file from  `test.py`. But it is giving me the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'`. how would I be able to read and print the `data.json` file?

Directories:

```
application folder
├── appFolder
│   ├──test.py
│   ├──data.json
│   
└── main.py
```

Code within `Main.py`

```
from appFolder import test
```

Code within `test.py`

```
import os
import json

TEST_FILENAME = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'MomentumStrats.json')
data = json.load(TEST_FILENAME)
print(data)
```

Inside `data.json`:

```
{
  "states": [
    {
      "name": "Alabama",
      "abbreviation": "AL",
      "area_codes": ["205", "251", "256", "334", "938"]
    }
}
```

Comment: From which directory are you starting the program?

Comment: `Main.py` runs `test.py` and the `test.py` reads and prints the `data.json` file

Comment: And from where are you starting `Main.py`?

Comment: I just start `Main.py` manually and it runs the other files

Comment: And *from which directory*? What do you type to start it?

Comment: I made a diagram of the `Directories` .`Main.py` is within the application folder

Comment: I don't want to know where the file *is* but *from where you start it*. Since you are not aware of the difference, presumably it's the same. So `data.json` should be `appFolder/data.json` in the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an "always relative to current module" file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174211/how-to-make-an-always-relative-to-current-module-file-path)

Comment: Hi I have tried to use the link you sent, I have updated the issues `test.py` file it recognizes the json file but I still cant get it to read.