# python script read in from subscript not finding file in directory even though the os.listdir sees it and subscript works fine on its own

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

I am reading a python subscript into a python script. The subscript uses an excel file in it's working directory. The structure looks like this

```
main_folder ->
  main.py
  subfolder ->
   data.xlsx
   submain.py
```

My main script calls the subscript as such:

```
from subfolder.submain import df
```

My `submain.py` script looks as such:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
```

However on my `main.py` script I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.xlsx'
```

This is strange because not only does `submain.py` run fine by itself, a quick `os.listdir()` shows the file to be there:

```
for f in os.listdir('subfolder'):
print(f)

data.xlsx
submain.py
```

Does anyone understand this behaviour? Many thanks

Comment: main.py works in its containing folder, that does not contain data.xslx. Now I'm not sure what's the best way to fix that is.

Comment: Finally found a post that addresses this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174211/how-to-make-an-always-relative-to-current-module-file-path

Answer (score 0):

It's a path problem: since submain.py is imported by main.py, your file is looked for in the working directory, `main_folder`; to fix that, add the absolute path to your `pd.read_excel` statement in submain.py:

```
import os
df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data.xlsx'))
```