# Convert seconds to weeks-days-hours-minutes-seconds in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a Python script for 'Enter the number of Seconds' and get results in weeks, days, hours, minutes and seconds. Here is what I have, but I am not getting the correct answers. What am I doing wrong?

```
seconds = raw_input("Enter the number of seconds:")
seconds = int(seconds)

minutes = seconds/60

seconds = seconds % 60

hours = minutes/60
hours = seconds/3600

minutes = minutes % 60

days = hours/24
days = minutes/1440
days = seconds/86400

hours = hours % 60
hours = minutes % 60
hours = seconds % 3600

weeks = days/7
weeks = hours/168
weeks = minutes/10080
weeks = seconds/604800

days = days % 1
days = hours % 24
days = minutes % 1440
days = seconds % 86400

weeks = weeks % 1
weeks = days % 7
weeks = hours % 168
weeks = minutes % 10080
weeks = seconds % 604800

print weeks, 'weeks', days, 'days', hours, 'hours', minutes, 'minutes', seconds, 'seconds'
```

Comment: when dividing use float and not int, i.e. 24.0 or float(24) and not 24, also in this context % mean modulo, check online what that is

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: @aIKid obviously python 2 from the last line

Comment: @Guy For what he wants to calculate, you're wrong. integer divison is exactly what he should use. For example, 80 seconds give 80/60=1 min and 80 % 60 gives 20 seconds remaining.

Comment: Duplicate of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048651/python-function-to-convert-seconds-into-minutes-hours-and-days?rq=1

Comment: @zhangxaochen Ah, didn't see that

Comment: I'm using 2.7.6 because that's what we're using in my class.

Comment: FYI, the `divmod` function will return the quotient and remainder in one operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Python function to convert seconds into minutes, hours, and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048651/python-function-to-convert-seconds-into-minutes-hours-and-days)*

Answer (score 11):

Just from the basic conversion principles:

```
weeks = seconds / (7*24*60*60)
days = seconds / (24*60*60) - 7*weeks
hours = seconds / (60*60) - 7*24*weeks - 24*days
minutes = seconds / 60 - 7*24*60*weeks - 24*60*days - 60*hours
seconds = seconds - 7*24*60*60*weeks - 24*60*60*days - 60*60*hours - 60*minutes
```

A bit of a less noisy way of doing the same thing:

```
weeks = seconds / (7*24*60*60)
seconds -= weeks*7*24*60*60
days = seconds / (24*60*60)
seconds -= days*24*60*60
hours = seconds / (60*60)
seconds -= hours*60*60
minutes = seconds / 60
seconds -= minutes *60
```

---

A cleaner version of again the same thing with `divmod` function which returns both division result and remainder in a tuple `(division, remainder)`:

```
weeks, seconds = divmod(seconds, 7*24*60*60)
days, seconds = divmod(seconds, 24*60*60)
hours, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60*60)
minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
```

Basically, this solution is closest to your attempt since this is what `divmod` does:

```
weeks, seconds = divmod(seconds, 7*24*60*60)
```

equivalent to

```
weeks = seconds / (7*24*60*60)
seconds = seconds % (7*24*60*60)
```

Here we are essentially finding the number of whole weeks in our time and keeping what is left after these weeks are removed.

---

And also you can go from the other end to make it even prettier:

```
minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
days, hours = divmod(hours, 24)
weeks, days = divmod(days, 7)
```

The idea behind this is that the number of seconds in your answer is the remainder after dividing them in minutes; minutes are the remainder of dividing all minutes into hours etc... This version is better because you can easily adjust it to months, years, etc...

Comment: That was fast, thank you!  Quick question (prob a stupid one)....Why is there no need for an %?  Are the - a subtraction sign?  So, Minutes is seconds/60 -(minus 7*24*60*weeks) -(minus 24*60*days)??  Again, very new.

Comment: @user3230374: `-` is subtraction. The modulo operation is being calculated through the mathematical identity `x % y == x - (x/y)*y`. Personally, I would have used `%` or `divmod`, but it's inconsequential.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the help!  One more question...What does the -= do?  How does that differ from just an =

Comment: x -= 1 is equivalent to x = x - 1; x += 1 is equivalent to x = x + 1.

Answer (score 2):

Using Python's datetime timedeltas with support for milliseconds or microseconds.

```
import datetime
def convert(sec): 
    td = datetime.timedelta(seconds=sec, microseconds=sec-int(sec)) 
    return td.days/7, (td.days/7)%7, td.seconds/3600, (td.seconds/60)%60, td.seconds%60, td.microseconds, td.microseconds/1000

seconds = 8*24*60*60 + 21627.123  # 8 days, 6 hours (21600 seconds), 27.123 seconds
w, d, h, m, s, us, ms = convert(seconds)
print '{}s / {}w {}d {}h {}m {}s {}us {}ms'.format(seconds,w,d,h,m,s,us,ms)

712827.123s / 1w 1d 6h 0m 27s 123000us 123ms
```

Comment: Why do you have microseconds before milliseconds?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for catching this!  For my use case time was in microseconds, I added milliseconds as an afterthought.

Answer (score 0):

```
def humanize_duration(amount, units='s'):
INTERVALS = [(lambda mlsec:divmod(mlsec, 1000), 'ms'),
             (lambda seconds:divmod(seconds, 60), 's'),
             (lambda minutes:divmod(minutes, 60), 'm'),
             (lambda hours:divmod(hours, 24), 'h'),
             (lambda days:divmod(days, 7), 'D'),
             (lambda weeks:divmod(weeks, 4), 'W'),
             (lambda years:divmod(years, 12), 'M'),
             (lambda decades:divmod(decades, 10), 'Y')]

for index_start, (interval, unit) in enumerate(INTERVALS):
    if unit == units:
        break

amount_abrev = []
last_index = 0
amount_temp = amount
for index, (formula, abrev) in enumerate(INTERVALS[index_start: len(INTERVALS)]):
    divmod_result = formula(amount_temp)
    amount_temp = divmod_result[0]
    amount_abrev.append((divmod_result[1], abrev))
    if divmod_result[1] > 0:
        last_index = index
amount_abrev_partial = amount_abrev[0: last_index + 1]
amount_abrev_partial.reverse()

final_string = ''
for amount, abrev in amount_abrev_partial:
    final_string += str(amount) + abrev + ' '
return final_string
```