# Search a list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and I want to find if a value exits in the list and if it exists return the dictionary.
For example

```
Mylist= [{'Stringa': "ABC",
          'Stringb': "DE",
          'val': 5},
             {'Stringa': "DEF",
          'Stringb': "GHI",
          'val': 6}]
```

I want to find if for any dictionary

dict["stringa"]=="ABC". If yes return the corresponding dictionary.
I used the function "any"

```
any(d['Stringa'] == 'ABC' for d in Mylist)
```

but it just gives True/False. How can I get the corresponding dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any` will just check if any of the items in the iterable satisfy the condition or not. It cannot be used to retrieve matching items.

Use a list comprehension to get the list of matched items, like this

```
matches = [d for d in Mylist if d['Stringa'] == 'ABC']
```

This will iterate through the list of dictionaries and whenever it finds a match, it will include that in the result list. And then you can access the actual dictionary with its index in the list, like `matches[0]`.

Alternatively, you can use a generator expression, like this

```
matches = (d for d in Mylist if d['Stringa'] == 'ABC')
```

and you can get the next matched item from the list, with

```
actual_dict = next(matches)
```

This will give you the actual dictionary. If you want to get the next matched item, you can call `next` with the generator expression again. If you want to get all the matching items at once, as a list, you can simply do

```
list_of_matches = list(matches)
```

**Note:** Calling `next()` will raise an exception, if there are no more items to be retrieved from the generator. So, you can pass a default value to be returned.

```
actual_dict = next(matches, None)
```

Now, `actual_dict` will be `None` if the generator is exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

Use `next()`:

```
d = next((d for d in Mylist if d['Stringa'] == 'ABC'), None)
if d is not None: # found
    print(d)
```

See [Python: find first element in a sequence that matches a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8534256/4279).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, which allows you a bit more flexibility:

```
def search_things(haystack, needle, value):
   for i in haystack:
      if i.get(needle) == value:
         return i
   return None # Not needed, None is returned by default
               # you can use this to return some other default value

found = search_things(MyList, 'StringA', 'ABC')
if found:
   print('Found it! {}'.format(found))
else:
   print('Not found')
```