# Express time in hours units to verbose time

Tags: python, datetime

I need express my time in Hours and minutes. This is what I have:

```
0.0425 hours
```

`~153` seconds, How can I show this as `0 Hours 2 minutos 33 seconds`?

Comment: Will the input always be in hours?

Comment: Wouldn't 0.425 hours be 25mins 30secs?

Comment: 0.425 hours != 0 Hours 2 minutos 33 seconds  you can check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048651/python-function-to-convert-seconds-into-minutes-hours-and-days

Comment: @Jkdc You're right, that was a typo, I edited.

Comment: @gtlambert Yes, the input will be always in hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
time = '0.0425 hours'


# Extract time from string
time = time.split()[0]

# Convert time to a number of hours, then a number of seconds
time = float(time)
time = int(time * 3600)

# Compute the constituent elements of the time
hours = time // 3600
minutes = (time // 60) % 60
seconds = time % 60

# Print the result
print '{hours} Hours {minutes} minutos {seconds} seconds'.format(
    hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
```

Comment: I like to use `divmod` here: `hours, seconds = divmod(time, 3600)` followed by `minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)`.

Comment: @chepner that looks nice

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import re

secs = int(re.sub('\D', '','~153'))
print '%d hours %d minutos %s seconds'%(time.gmtime(secs)[3:6])
```