# Command cooldown format

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

hello i added a few minutes cool-down for commands its working fine. but for some commands i added few hours cool-down but it showing 900 minutes and 30 seconds. so how to make below code to show hours, minutes and seconds.

```
elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
    m, s = divmod(error.retry_after, 60)
    fmt = "Try again in {} minutes and {} seconds" \
        .format(round(m), round(s))
    try:
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, fmt)
    except discord.Forbidden:
        pass
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/python-format-timedelta-to-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python function to convert seconds into minutes, hours, and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048651/python-function-to-convert-seconds-into-minutes-hours-and-days)

Comment: `h, m = divmod(m, 60)` after your current `divmod` line.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  thanks. anyway i added same after researching.