# How to get time humanized time difference without external libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have two times, how can I get the time difference of these 2 aware datetime objects in a human readable format. What I mean by human readable format would be `1 year 3 months 2 weeks 4 days 1 hour 2 minutes and 19 seconds`.

However, if the time difference is shorter, it would give a readable format like `2 minutes and 3 seconds` (It wouldn't tell us `0 years 0 months 0 weeks 0 days 0 hours 2 minutes and 52 seconds`). Or if its just seconds left then it would be `15 seconds`

- Year is classified as 365.25 days
- Month is classified as 30.4375 days

Comment: There's no built-in module to do that, so you'd probably have to implement it yourself using `timedelta.total_seconds()` and `divmod`.

Comment: It's going to be interesting since seconds is the only of your units that has fixed length.

Comment: FWIW, a month is an extremely vague unit of time (and to a lesser degree year too), so giving both a pretty vague "3 months" and a hyper specific "19 seconds" is… odd…

Comment: @deceze updated question

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048651/python-function-to-convert-seconds-into-minutes-hours-and-days/24542445#24542445) might be a place to start