# Python datetime to string without microsecond component

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I'm adding UTC time strings to Bitbucket API responses that currently only contain Amsterdam (!) time strings. For consistency with the UTC time strings returned elsewhere, the desired format is `2011-11-03 11:07:04` (followed by `+00:00`, but that's not germane).

What's the best way to create such a string (*without* a microsecond component) from a `datetime` instance *with* a microsecond component?

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print unicode(datetime.datetime.now())
2011-11-03 11:13:39.278026
```

I'll add the best option that's occurred to me as a possible answer, but there may well be a more elegant solution.

**Edit:** I should mention that I'm not *actually* printing the current time – I used `datetime.now` to provide a quick example. So the solution should not assume that any `datetime` instances it receives will include microsecond components.

Answer (score 1102, accepted):

If you want to format a `datetime` object in a specific format that is different from the standard format, it's best to explicitly specify that format:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2011-11-03 18:21:26'
```

See [the documentation of `datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for an explanation of the `%` directives.

Starting from Python 3.6, the `isoformat()` method is flexible enough to also produce this format:

```
datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(sep=" ", timespec="seconds")
```

Comment: What was that convincing case - putting this solution above your solution using datetime.replace?

Comment: @matlehmann: Of course I don't know the arguments of davidchambers' colleague.  However, I think if your intention is to print a date in a very specific format, you should be explicit about this intention.  The code in this answer  says "take the current time and format it exactly like this".  The code in the other answer says "take the current time, set the microseconds to 0, and then convert it to a string somehow".

Comment: +1, being explicit about the string format avoids problems if standard datetime-str conversion changes in a future Python version

Comment: Is inventing your own format really the solution? Or even duplicating by hand an existing standardized format? Maybe if interoperability isn't a concern, but why not use ISO format? In which case, the other solution is more clear and more explicit (noting Bengt's comment). Manual format strings generally violate DRY, either on a project level (if you hardcode them as above) or on a community level (unless you're really inventing a new datetime format).

Comment: @DylanYoung The requirement of the OP is to print a datetime object in a format that is _different_ from the standard format returned by `.isoformat()`, which includes the microseconds by default.  If that's what you need, be explicit about it.  Everyone will immediately understand what this code does.  Hardly anyone will understand the other code without looking at the documentation.

Comment: @SvenMarnach My bad; I didn't see the specified format in the question (just thought they wanted microseconds left out). `.isoformat()` will leave out microseconds if they are zero.

Comment: @DylanYoung which ISO format? There are several. Why risk making your code dependent on changes that are decided by a 3rd party? First and foremost, standards must be consistent across the project, which might include several platforms. You can't do that by relying on conventions agreed upon in the merely _current version_ of the platform. And what if needs require one to migrate the code to another platform? In JS it's `2017-05-11T12:54:23.123Z`, in PHP it's `2017-05-11T12:54:23+00:00`. So which one is "ISO"? Don't be a menace. Use explicit formats.

Comment: @AlexanderMP Are you kidding? ISO Formats exist *to* ensure compatibility between platforms.  Unfortunately their adoption is slow, exactly *because* every person decides to 'roll their own' format.  To ensure internal consistency? Maybe, but break external compatibility.

Comment: @DylanYoung In my line of work I integrate with multiple systems. I've integrated with dozens, and each of them had a different date/time format. Similar, but different. And according to the ISO 8601 specification https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 it's all ISO. Relying on one specific format that is currently being output when converting to string, as a given, is just foolish, as it is subject to change, and break everything. Especially with all the hacks seen in other answers (string operations, or the microsecond hack).

Comment: @DylanYoung moreover, these multiple systems, that all use ISO datetime format, can't integrate out of the box. One still has to use slow fuzzy parsers when dealing with them. Which is why, to ensure compatibility, within a project, a very strict format has to be chosen - a literal format. Of course it should be an ISO format. But if you rely on implicit conversions to string, well, you're really not gonna get far, as I've clearly shown with the differences between JS, PHP, Python, and don't get me started with all the SQL flavors.

Comment: @AlexanderMP  I suppose if you're concerned with the efficiency of parsing your dates, it makes sense to use a stricter subset of ISO, but the ISO datetime format is unambiguous, so if python can't natively parse a Java ISO datetime format, that is a weakness in the python's datetime tools.  Actually, last I looked python didn't even have a native ISO parser (though that was python 2: ridiculous.  In this case, a third party library that does fully support ISO is on order.

Comment: @DylanYoung or in this case accept inevitability and ensure unquestionable compatibility by enforcing a specific strict format on all dates on all subsystems.

Comment: @AlexanderMP  Internal compatibility is not compatibility; that's why we have standards. But yes, as long as you're using ISO format, sure speed up your parsing by using a stricter subset.  But for the sake of everyone, encapsulate your format in a method or function.

Comment: A question that specifies an ISO-8601 date, should never have an answer that manually builds that ISO-8601 date by hand.

Comment: @CaptainCrunch The question doesn't specify an [ISO-8601 date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). So while it's possible you have a point with your statement, it simply doesn't apply here.

Comment: As of Python 3.6, you can simply do: `datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='seconds', sep=' ')`

Answer (score 219):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print unicode(now.replace(microsecond=0))
2011-11-03 11:19:07
```

Comment: I think, this is the right solution, because it is readable and documented and consistent behavior: ["`.isoformat([sep])` - Return a string representing the date and time in ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmmmm or, if microsecond is 0, YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat)

Comment: in my situation, the date has already been constructed and I needed to "floor" it to the second.  this is perfect, thanks.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: Far better than formatting or parsing strings for the comparison, thank you.

Comment: This is the right answer as it upholds the format datetime, not turning it into string. But it can be shortened further by removing third line and changing second line of code to `now = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)`. Also worth mentioning that datetime.datetime.utcnow() prints GMT—never store timestamps in local time

Comment: Also works when saving this in a datetime field in the DB.

Answer (score 154):

In Python 3.6:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now().isoformat(' ', 'seconds')
'2017-01-11 14:41:33'
```

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

Comment: I think that now, 8 years later with the advent of Python 3.6 this should be the accepted, universal answer. This offers the better of both worlds argued about by @DylanYoung and AlexanderMP on this same thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7999977/6118556)

Comment: [How to install Python 3.7 on Linux](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/)

Comment: I have always hated that 'T' in my times. I did not know of the separator option until now. Thank you and 1+.

Answer (score 55):

This is the way I do it. ISO format:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
# Returns: '2017-01-23T14:58:07'
```

You can replace the 'T' if you don't want ISO format:

```
datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(' ')
# Returns: '2017-01-23 15:05:27'
```

Comment: This is similar to my answer. Is there a reason to favour `.isoformat()` over `unicode()`?

Comment: Depends on what you want, if you want the python string representation use `unicode()`, and if you want ISO-8601, use `isoformat()`

Comment: I see. `unicode()` is more convenient than `.isoformat().replace('T', ' ')`, certainly. ;)

Comment: I would just use Sven's solution for non-iso format, its more explicit: datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") , but replacing the 'T' is just another way. May be best solution if you need both ISO and unicode date.

Comment: `isoformat` accepts the separator specifier, so no replace should be done. just do: `datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(' ')`

Answer (score 19):

Yet another option:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2011-11-03 11:31:28'
```

By default this uses local time, if you need UTC you can use the following:

```
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
'2011-11-03 18:32:20'
```

Comment: Downvote because the OP asked about datetime, not time.

Answer (score 18):

Keep the first 19 characters that you wanted via slicing:

```
>>> str(datetime.datetime.now())[:19]
'2011-11-03 14:37:50'
```

Comment: This is only incorrect because time strings can have timezone specification appended, e.g. `+05:30`. Correct would be `str(now())[:19]`.

Comment: @K3---rnc:  Thanks.  Updated per your suggestion.

Comment: after year `10000`, a second will be missed

Comment: time will tell @diti ;)

Answer (score 18):

I usually do:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = now.replace(microsecond=0)  # To print now without microsecond.

# To print now:
print(now)
```

output:

```
2019-01-13 14:40:28
```

Answer (score 10):

As of Python 3.6+, the best way of doing this is by the new [`timespec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) argument for `isoformat`.

```py
isoformat(timespec='seconds', sep=' ')
```

Usage:

```py
>>> datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='seconds')
'2020-10-16T18:38:21'
>>> datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='seconds', sep=' ')
'2020-10-16 18:38:35'
```

Answer (score 8):

Since not all `datetime.datetime` instances have a microsecond component (i.e. when it is zero), you can partition the string on a "." and take only the first item, which will always work:

```
unicode(datetime.datetime.now()).partition('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

**f-string formatting**

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print(f'{datetime.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}')
2021-12-01 22:10:07
```

Answer (score 3):

We can try something like below

```
import datetime

date_generated = datetime.datetime.now()
date_generated.replace(microsecond=0).isoformat(' ').partition('+')[0]
```

Comment: This is inferior to `.isoformat(' ', 'seconds')`, proposed in an earlier answer.

Comment: When I am trying above proposed earlier answer, I am getting below error

>>> datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(' ', 'seconds')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isoformat() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Ah, I see. It works for me in Python 3 but not in Python 2.

Comment: I am using python 3.4.3 version, in that i see that error.

>>> datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(' ', 'seconds')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isoformat() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %X")
>>> print(dt)
'2021-02-05 04:10:24'
```

Answer (score 2):

This I use because I can understand and hence remember it better (and date time format also can be customized based on your choice) :-

```
import datetime
moment = datetime.datetime.now()
print("{}/{}/{} {}:{}:{}".format(moment.day, moment.month, moment.year,
                                 moment.hour, moment.minute, moment.second))
```

Comment: Brilliant. Simple, flexible and platform-independent (unlike strftime).

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the simplest way.

```
>>> t = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> t
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 30, 17, 21, 26, 606191)
>>> t = str(t).split('.')
>>> t
['2018-11-30 17:21:26', '606191']
>>> t = t[0]
>>> t
'2018-11-30 17:21:26'
>>>
```

Comment: datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2011-11-03 18:21:26' much easier imo. But easy is not alwast the best

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following method

```
import datetime as _dt

ts = _dt.datetime.now().timestamp()
print("TimeStamp without microseconds: ", int(ts)) #TimeStamp without microseconds:  1629275829

dt = _dt.datetime.now()
print("Date & Time without microseconds: ", str(dt)[0:-7]) #Date & Time without microseconds:  2021-08-18 13:07:09
```

Answer (score -2):

Current TimeStamp without microsecond component:

```
timestamp = list(str(datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())).split('.'))[0]
```

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer in the format that was requested.