# Python assert equal except one attribute

Tags: python, assert

### Updated

Thank you all for the suggestions, but I'm having a new issue here.

Since I'm comparing two `datetime.datetime` objects and I didn't realize that it doesn't have attribute `items` or `keys` to iterate from, some valid answers provided below no longer work. I'm refactoring my dummy data here to better reflect my use cases,

```
# Two datetime that I want to assert equal as long as they are equal to the 'second'
now = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 11, 36, 49, 811000)
then = datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 22, 11, 36, 49, 811099)

assert now == then # this for sure will return false
```

As you can see from the example, every attribute but 'microsecond' is equal. Anyway to loop through the attributes and compare?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you need all except for any one? Or all except for a specific one?

Comment: All except for a specific one, this case `attr3`

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999935/python-datetime-to-string-without-microsecond-component -- try `assert now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") == then.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: @xnx It worked! I just need to assert the `then.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") == now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`! And this could also be useful if someone wants to assert equal to day, hour, minute, etc. Please edit your answer below and I will take it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Have edited my answer with another suggestion as well.

Comment: @benjaminz This is why you need to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: for your modified question, you can use:

```
assert now.replace(microsecond=0) == then.replace(microsecond=0)
```

or

```
assert now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") == then.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

To explicitly exclude `attr3` in particular (and ensure that its value *isn't* the same in each dictionary):

```
assert all([foo[k] == bar[k] for k in bar.keys() if k != 'attr3']) and foo['attr3'] != bar['attr3']
```

Perhaps the following will help:

```
assert sum([foo[k]!=v for (k,v) in bar.items()]) == 1
```

(but you'd need to be sure that the keys are the same in both dictionaries).

Comment: I'm assuming this is to get the sum of all assert failures? What if there is a case where `foo[attr2] != bar[attr2]` but `foo[attr3] == bar[attr3]`? sum here is the same but it is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the attributes you want to compare, and assert for each.

```
compared_keys = foo.pop('attr3').keys()
for k in compared_keys:
    assert(foo[k] == bar[k])
```

Comment: `{'attr3': 3}.keys().pop('attr3')` -> `TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: @warvariuc Right, corrected - first pop from the dictionary, than get the list of keys. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
foo = {
  'attr1': 1,
  'attr2': 2,
  'attr3': 3
}

bar = {
  'attr1': 1,
  'attr2': 2,
  'attr3': 3
}

assert (sum([foo[k] == v for k, v in bar.items() if k != 'attr3'])) == 2
print('Works')

foo = {
  'attr1': 1,
  'attr2': 2,
  'attr3': 3
}

bar = {
  'attr1': 1,
  'attr2': 2,
  'attr3': 300
}

assert (sum([foo[k] == v for k, v in bar.items() if k != 'attr3'])) == 2
print('Works')
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if their `attr3` accidentally equals

Comment: Yes it will. It just completely ignores attr3.

Comment: Oh I just saw the k != 'attr3'

Comment: @benjaminz Right, that tells the list comprehension to ignore any key called 'attr3'.