# How to remove Millisecond using python?

Tags: python-2.7

I Have fetched timestamp from my log file but i need to remove millisecond and write it back to a new file.

i.e Ex:3:32:15.89567

I need to remove .89567
Finally i need is 3:32:15(hour,minute and second)

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: Have you done any effort yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python datetime to string without microsecond component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999935/python-datetime-to-string-without-microsecond-component)

Answer (score 0):

Cut the string at the first '.' from the right with the rfind string method :

```
my_string  = '3:32:15.89567'
cut_string = my_string[ : my_string.rfind('.') ]
```