# Add current date time to the uploaded file in django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I am trying to add `date` and `time` to the uploaded file.

If the filename is `filename.xml` then I would like to change the name to `filename-<date>-<time>.xml`

```
def handle_uploaded_file(self, f):
    name = "static/uploads/{0}".format(f.name)
    with open(name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of issues are you facing in the current approach ?

Comment: There are no issues currently. The file is uploading. How can I insert the date time with `format(f.name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datetime` module to get date and time separately.

**Solution**:

```
from datetime import datetime
def handle_uploaded_file(self, f):
    _datetime = datetime.now()
    datetime_str = _datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
    # if there are more than one dots
    file_name_split = f.name.split('.')
    file_name_list = file_name_split[:-1]
    ext = file_name_split[-1]
    file_name_wo_ext = '.'.join(file_name_list)

    name = '/path/to/uploads/{0}-{1}.{2}'.format(file_name_wo_ext, datetime_str, ext)
    # rest of the code
```

Ref: [datetime module in Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999935/python-datetime-to-string-without-microsecond-component) if you want to remove the microsecond component from time.

Comment: Got this  -- `[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'static/uploads/test.xml-2017-09-05-20:30:13.515619'`

Comment: I am using Python 3.4

Comment: Are you on a Windows OS?

Comment: Yes I am on windows. Sorry I would have told this to you before.

Comment: colon (:) seem to be the issue in time. Let me update the answer.

Comment: There is no error. But the file has become -- `test.xml-2017-09-05-20-47-40`

Comment: I need to split the filename and extension and then concatenate.

Comment: Sorted. Got help from Adarsh's answer as well. Thanks Adarsh.        `file_name,extension = name.split('.')
        modified_name = file_name+'-'+datetime_str
        name = modified_name+'.'+extension`

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Awesome. Yes there can be more than one dots. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation with datetime module. Look below for the small snippet as an example.

```
import datetime
name = 'filename.xml'
name = name[:-4] + '_'+str(today.ctime()) + '_.xml'
print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
def handle_uploaded_file(self, f):
    name = "static/uploads/{0}".format(f.name)
    file_name,extension = name.split('.')
    modified_name = file_name+''+date_time
    name = modified_name+extension
    with open(name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Getting an error  `date_time = datetime.now()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'`

Comment: Made the correction, it should have been datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: Now getting - `import datetime.datetime
ImportError: No module named 'datetime.datetime'; 'datetime' is not a package`

Comment: Made a slight correction, this code should work according to python 2.x but I'm not sure about 3.x