# How to convert client side datetime into server level date time

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting the `date-time` from the client like this:

```
Thu Mar 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I want to convert it into:

```
2020-03-12
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python datetime to string without microsecond component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999935/python-datetime-to-string-without-microsecond-component)

Comment: Please post your working code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
import datetime
date_now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
print (str(date_now))
```

or

```
print(str(datetime.datetime.now().date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

the output will be:

```
'2020-03-02'
```

For more information please look the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#module-datetime).