# Microsecond must be in 0..999999 (Get outlook e-mail time)

Tags: python

I want to extract received date and time for each e-mail in my inbox, but I'm getting microsecond error.

How to get outlook email time without microseconds? Is there a way to strip it?

```
import win32com.client
import csv
import pandas as pd

head = [("Subject","Body","receivedtime")]  

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = outlook.Folders.item(1)
inbox2020= root_folder.Folders["Caixa de Entrada 2020"]
messages = inbox2020.Items

message = messages.GetFirst()
print (message.receivedtime)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python datetime to string without microsecond component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999935/python-datetime-to-string-without-microsecond-component)

Comment: Hi, no i think my problem was in mapi commands, now i'm using senton instead of receivedtime, and all works fine, ty for help

Comment: _but I'm getting microsecond error._ What does that mean? Is your program throwing an actual exception?

Comment: Hi AMC, when debuging the code one of me lines display this error: Microsecond must be in 0..999999.

But is solved i changed message.receivedtime for message.senton, that way mapi dont get microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Find solution using senton instead of receivedtime.