# Add values of 02:12, 03:45... from a list together to make a format time = hours:minutes:seconds

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert a string into minutes and then add it all up and return it as a string, I'm having difficulties doing this.

I have a list that holds this:

TimeL = ['02:32','03:43','01:05','56:03']

I want to add these minutes:seconds together and return a value thats the total in the format hours:mm:ss but if their value is not enough to make an hour, i just want to return a value thats mm:ss.

so far all I can do is convert each thing into seconds and add them up, but this is not what I want, its just what I knew how to do.

```
def getTIME(s):
    l = s.split(":")
    return int(l[0])*(60) + int(l[1])


for i in range(len(TimeL)):
        NEW = getTIME(TimeL[i])
        NewTotalTime = NewTotalTime + NEW
```

so my method will return a value thats only seconds.. so like 3432 seconds. I want it to be hours:minutes:seconds and Im stuck. Anyone can help even a little bit would be great thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Time Seconds to h:m:s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3432))
```

You'll need to import the `datetime` module for this. You already have the number of seconds and this will convert it to a string with hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want. 1 min = 60 seconds, so you divide the seconds by 60. Your problem is that you need to divide by 60.0 in python so that you get the exact value (float value). Once you have this, you take the lowest integer value (`math.floor`), e.g. 150 seconds is 2.5 minutes, so you take 2 minutes, 2 minutes is 120 seconds, you remove that from 150 you get 30. This is the remaining number of seconds. You apply the same reasoning for hours (60 minutes)

```
import sys
import math

def getSeconds(s):
    l = s.split(":")
    return int(l[0])*(60) + int(l[1])

def getTotalString(time_list):
    total_secs = 0
    for time_str in time_list:
        total_secs += getSeconds(time_str)

    total_mins = total_secs/60.0
    mins = math.floor(total_mins)
    secs = total_secs-mins*60

    if mins<60:
        return '%.2d:%.2d' % (mins, secs)
    else:
        hours = math.floor(mins/60.0)
        mins = mins-60*hours
        return '%.2d:%.2d:%.2d' % (hours, mins, secs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print getTotalString(sys.argv[1:])
```

The approach for calculating the sum of seconds can be done in one line in Python:

```
total_secs = sum(getSeconds(time_str) for time_str in time_list)
```

The `sum` will calculate the sum of the numbers in a list (or iterator). You can provide it with a list of numbers or a generator of numbers to be added which is `the number of seconds in each time string in the list`

I hope I made it as clear and as instructive as possible, but you can use the simpler solution of the datetime module.

**UPDATE:** This is Python 2.x not Python 3. so it might not work as expected, but the idea is the same, the syntax is different.