# Python Time conversion h:m:s to seconds

Tags: python, datetime, formatting

I am aware that with the timedelta function you can convert seconds to h:m:s using something like:

```
>> import datetime
>> str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=666)) 
'0:11:06'
```

But I need to convert h:m:s to seconds, or minutes.

Do you know a function that can do this?

Comment: What is your source input?  A timestamp string?  Some sort of object?

Comment: Do you mean seconds or minutes since the epoch? Or do you just want to extract the seconds and minute parts from the timestamp?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049805/add-values-of-0212-0345-from-a-list-together-to-make-a-format-time-hours

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def hms_to_seconds(t):
    h, m, s = [int(i) for i in t.split(':')]
    return 3600*h + 60*m + s
```

Comment: Nice and simple, though I think you want to return `datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600*h + 60*m + s)`.

Answer (score 14):

```
>>> import time, datetime
>>> a = time.strptime("00:11:06", "%H:%M:%S")
>>> datetime.timedelta(hours=a.tm_hour, minutes=a.tm_min, seconds=a.tm_sec).seconds
666
```

And here's a cheeky one liner if you're really intent on splitting over ":"

```
>>> s = "00:11:06"
>>> sum(int(i) * 60**index for index, i in enumerate(s.split(":")[::-1]))
666
```

Comment: Note that this fails if the number of hours exceeds 23.

Comment: @BrendanWood more generally, it fails if the string passed to `strptime` is not a valid time.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not as trivial as constructing a `datetime` object from a string using `datetime.strptime`.  This question has been asked previously on Stack Overflow here: [How to construct a timedelta object from a simple string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string) , where the solution involved using [python-dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil).

Alternatively, if you don't want to have to add another module, here is a class you can use to parse a `timedelta` from a string: http://kbyanc.blogspot.ca/2007/08/python-reconstructing-timedeltas-from.html

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def tt(a):
...     b = a.split(':')
...     return int(b[0]) * 3600 + int(b[1]) * 60 + int(b[2])
... 
>>> print tt('0:11:06')
```

666

Answer (score 0):

This works in 2.6.4:

```
hours, minutes, seconds = [int(_) for _ in thestring.split(':')]
```

If you want to turn it back into a timedelta:

```
thetimedelta = datetime.timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
```

Comment: Nolen's answer is much cleaner -- I did not see the strptime function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure I'd bother with timedelta for this

```
>>> pseconds = lambda hms:sum(map(lambda a,b: int(a)*b,hms.split(':'),(3600,60,1)))
>>> pseconds('0:11:06')
666
```

Comment: I'd use list comprehension here instead of `map`. I think it would be much clearer...

Comment: right, almost always prefer list comprehension to map...here, it wouldn't have been simpler because it would have required a zip whereas map can handle multiple sequences.  6 of one, half-dozen...look's kind of ugly both ways

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import anything!

```
def time(s):
  m = s // 60
  h = (m // 60) % 60
  m %= 60
  s %= 60
  return h,m,s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to handle a string like `'23:32'` or `'07'`, then you can use the following function:

```
def get_seconds(time_string):
    time_list = time_string.split(':')
    seconds = 0 
    for i in range(len(time_list),0,-1):
        t = int(time_list[i-1])*60**(time_len-(i))
        seconds += t
    return seconds
```