# Another converting hh:mm:ss to seconds

Tags: python

I have seen a few questions that want the same except in my situation the time format isn't always hh:mm:ss, sometimes it's just mm:ss

I understand the idea mentioned here [How to convert an H:MM:SS time string to seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402812/how-to-convert-an-hmmss-time-string-to-seconds-in-python) and here [Python Time conversion h:m:s to seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742296/python-time-conversion-hms-to-seconds)

What i don't understand is how to deal with situations like hh:mm:ss, h:mm:ss, mm:ss or just m:ss

```
def getSec(s):
    l = s.split(':')
    return int(l[0]) * 3600 + int(l[1]) * 60 + int(l[2])
```

Edit:
I think my question isn't clear enough. I'm searching for a solution to handle all possible formats with 1 single function.

Comment: ... Is this for real?

Comment: Now it gives me a IndexError: list index out of range so i expected the code getSec to be faulty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def getSec(s):
    l = map(int, s.split(':')) # l = list(map(int, s.split(':'))) in Python 3.x
    return sum(n * sec for n, sec in zip(l[::-1], (1, 60, 3600)))

getSec('20') # 20
getSec('1:20') # 80
getSec('1:30:01') # 5401
```

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty much the same for all time formats. Check out the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module:

```
>>> s = "15:34:23"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 15, 34, 23)

>>> s = "34:23"  
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 34, 23)

>>> s = "4:34"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 4, 34)
```

`%H` is for hours, `%M` is for minutes, `%S` is for seconds. A list can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

---

As a function:

```
>>> def getSec(s):
...     L = s.split(':')
...     if len(L) == 1:
...             return L[0]
...     elif len(L) == 2:
...             datee = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%M:%S")
...             return datee.minute * 60 + datee.second
...     elif len(L) == 3:
...             datee = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S")
...             return datee.hour * 3600 + datee.minute * 60 + datee.second
...
>>> getSec("13:25:43")
48343
>>> getSec("25:43")
1543
>>> getSec("43")
43
```

Comment: Ok i'll have a look at it, thanks. The problem i have now is that with current code i'm getting a IndexError: list index out of range and i think that's because it expects h:m:s instead of the given m:s ?

Comment: @user1987032 Current code? Please do post it in your question

Answer (score 1):

the very latest version (just committed; 0.3.0 on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-date)) of [simple-date](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-date) extends Python's time formatting with optional expressions, a bit like regular expressions.  so `((H:)?M:)?S` will match just seconds, or minutes and seconds, or hours, minutes and seconds.

for example:

```
>>> from simpledate import *
>>> SimpleDate('56', format='((H:)?M:)?S').time
datetime.time(0, 0, 56, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Santiago' SMT-1 day, 19:17:00 STD>)
>>> SimpleDate('12:34:56', format='((H:)?M:)?S').time
datetime.time(12, 34, 56, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Santiago' SMT-1 day, 19:17:00 STD>)
>>> SimpleDate('34:56', format='((H:)?M:)?S').hour
0
>>> SimpleDate('34:56', format='((H:)?M:)?S').minute
34
>>> SimpleDate('34:56', format='((H:)?M:)?S').second
56
```

(the `America/Santiago` part is just because that's my local timezone - you can specify a timezone too if you want, with `tz='UTC'` or similar)

unfortunately there's no currently support for total seconds, so you still have to do that yourself.  i will think how to add it, though.

it's similar to regular expressions (where `?` means that something is optional).  you can also have alternatives with `(...|...|...)`.

[updated to reflect 0.3 syntax]