# How to convert the time portion of a Python datetime object to total number of seconds since start of the day

Tags: python, datetime, time, seconds

I have a script that returns a datetime object like so:

```
rec = record[14]    #index 14 is a straight datetime object
rec2 = rec.time()   #sends time part to rec2
```

All I want to do now is convert rec2 to seconds of type integer.  Any insight on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seconds from what reference point? Can you show us your output?

Comment: @khtad 14:54:02.547277 or 14:54:02.  Could be either one depending on the source.

Comment: Do you need "seconds since epoch" format? Also it's not clear what type `rec.time()` returns?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-object-to-seconds

Comment: @Dimpermanence So you would want 3 or 2, respectively?

Comment: @IvanNevostruev No, I do not need "seconds since epoch".  rec.time() simply returns the time port of datetime, i.e. HH:MM:SS.  I want an easy way to convert this to seconds of type integer.

Comment: @khtad 3 or 2?  I'm confused...

Comment: @Dimpermanence sorry, brainfart--did you want to round to the nearest second or take the floor function? E.g. 2.547277 rounds up to 3, but using int(2.547277) returns 2. 02 will also return 2. Does it matter if you get 2 or 3 as your return?

Comment: I see so you basically need seconds since start of the day.

Comment: @khtad  Err...maybe I could've been more clear.  I want to convert HH:MM:SS to total seconds.  Is that clear?  : )

Comment: @IvanNevostruev Ivan nailed it!

Comment: @IvanNevostruev That is exactly how I will edit this.  Sorry.  It's been a while on abstract algebra : )

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
rec2.hour*3600 + rec2.minute*60 + rec2.second
```

I also found this:

[Get seconds since midnight in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971308/get-seconds-since-midnight-in-python)

Comment: Obviously this is a good question because I felt it was pretty straightforward  : )  I simply want to convert the time portion of datetime to seconds.  And these seconds need to be of type integer, not string.

Comment: Argghh...see, that's what I'm doing but it looks...well, convoluted.  Not yours, mine.  Because mine has more steps and after a while it's like "c'mon, really?"

Comment: It does seem like there should be a simple way given a date to get seconds since midnight, but I haven't found anything better than this yet.

Comment: Well, I'm currently using this: s = int(sum(int(i) * 60**index for index, i in enumerate(rec2.split(":")[::-1]))) and this works but it's ridiculously complicated.

Comment: Actually, that seems like a clever answer, please post it.

Comment: It's one a grabbed from a similar post.  I will do so and cite the other developer and will just roll the dice on whether this will be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I had "solved" this conundrum earlier by adopting code from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742296/python-time-conversion-hms-to-seconds), although I had really hoped there was a more direct way.  I took @Nolen Royalty's "cheeky" one liner and wrapped it in the int() function is all.  In essence:

```
rec = record[14]       #stores index 14 of a list to rec which is a full datetime object
rec2 = rec.time()      #stores time portion of that datetime object to rec2
rec3 = rec2.strftime('%H:%M:%S')   #uses strftime to convert to string
s = int(sum(int(i) * 60**index for index, i in enumerate(rec3.split(":")[::-1])))  #converts that string to integer
```

Convoluted, but it works...still, if anyone has anything better I would be very intrigued.

Answer (score 0):

[The question *"Python Time conversion h:m:s to seconds"* (that you've linked)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10742296/4279) shows a simple efficient one-line solution on how to get an integer number of seconds since midnight that works for both `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.time` types:

```
from datetime import timedelta

secs = timedelta(hours=rec.hour, minutes=rec.minute, seconds=rec.second).seconds
```