# Calculating the average value from a timefield field in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to calculate average time of all records in database named time. The database i am using is sqlite3.

```
#models.py i have 

time=models.TimeField()
```

```
#vies.py i am trying to get this by using
time_all = Models.objects.values_list('time')
time_avg = Avg(time_all)
```

But time_avg is still a list of all time values

Comment: @Marco  This is how it will work, but i use sqlite3 and can't reference that way.

Comment: `values_ist` should be `values_list`

Comment: After that, you can implement your own logic to average the times like answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12034023/4151233

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
from django.db import Avg
Models.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('time'))
```

*although I do not understand the benefit of it*