# Timer Python 3,3

Tags: python, python-3.3

I was wondering how I would make my time in Python 3.3 display in minutes and seconds. At the minute, it only displays in seconds? Many Thanks.

```
start_time=time.time()

# program operation

end_time=time.time()-start_time
print(end_time)
```

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms

Comment: Well, do you know how to convert between minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` module

```
import datetime
end_time = 400 # this is the difference in your example, in seconds

str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = end_time))
```

Result

```
'0:06:40'
```

Comment: what function would I use to start the timer instead of start_time=time.time()

Comment: @user3565969 Why do you need a different function? The way you did it works fine, using `time.time()` before and after the operation.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dale\Desktop\Prog.py", line 11, in <module>
    start_time=time.time()
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
>>>

Comment: @user3565969 Did you `import time` in your code? That is where the function comes from.

Comment: I have import datetime

Comment: @user3565969 You must import `time` so you can use `time.time()` and you must import `datetime` so you can use `datetime.timedelta()`. They are two different modules and have a different set of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the datetime module. Some people use the time module with sleep() function, but it is inaccurate. By the level of you're experience with this, you should use time module.

```
import time
seconds = 0
minutes = 0
while True:
    print('\r'f'{minutes}:{seconds}', end='')
    time.sleep(1)
    seconds += 1
    if seconds == 60:
        minutes += 1
        seconds = 0
    elif minutes == 2:
        break*
```

The '\r' in print statement is to take the printing cursor in the terminal to the start of the line. Python by default adds a new line character(\n, the cursor goes to the next line.) to a string and therefore, set the 'end = none' for the string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use time module :

```
import time
def initial_input():
    global error
    global hours
    global minutes 
    global seconds
    error = 0
    hours = input("How much hours ? : ")
    minutes = input("How much minutes ? : ")
    seconds = input("How much seconds ? : ")
    try:
        hours,minutes,seconds = int(hours),int(minutes),int(seconds)
    except:
        print("input no ok")
        error = 1
        initial_input()
    if hours > 99 or minutes > 60 or seconds > 60:
        print("Error please input correct numbers")
        initial_input()
        error = 1
error = 0
initial_input()
if error == 0:
    max_range = hours*3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
    end_range = 0
    while end_range <= max_range -1:
        if minutes <= 0 and seconds <= 0:
            hours -= 1
            minutes = 60
        if seconds <= 0:
            minutes -=1
            seconds = 59
        else:
            seconds -=1
        print(f"\rThere is {hours} hours, {minutes} minutes, {seconds} seconds 
left !",end="")
        max_range -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
    print("\nNo time left ! ")
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? What is the problem and how did you fix it?

Comment: can you tell how to add centi-sec to this?