# Python: convert unix time to durations

Tags: python, datetime

```
a = time.time()
b = time.time()
c = b - a
```

I know c is in seconds. Is there a mod out there (maybe datetime or time) where it can convert the seconds into any form of duration?

for example:
I want to be able to say

```
print convert_time(c, days=True) 
print convert_time(c, hours=True)
```

and so forth....

I know I can just convert it manually but I was wondering if there were anything out there I can use instead of writing my own func.

Comment: `datetime.timedelta`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer has already been given [Python Time Seconds to h:m:s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms)

```
>>> import datetime
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=666))
'0:11:06'
```

I don't know how to mark the topic as duplicate. Forgive me for that.

Comment: As addition you may access to timedelta attributes for example: `datetime.timedelta(seconds=6660000).days`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil)'s [relativedelta](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) for this:

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> relativedelta(seconds=5000).hours
1
>>> relativedelta(seconds=5000).minutes
23
>>> relativedelta(seconds=5000).seconds
20
```

Plenty of other good options, too, but this has the kinds of conversion stuff built into it that I wish the stock `datetime.timedelta` had.