# How can I convert a time that is a number of seconds from a date to the actual date? [Python]

Tags: python, time, data-analysis

I have a list of that contains times. Each time is the number of seconds from Jan 1, 1904. This is not Unix or any other conversion I have familiar with. How can I convert this to the date?

An example of this is 3438012868.0 which is 3438012868.0 seconds from Jan 1, 1904. I want this date to be Dec 11, 2012, 1:00.30 pm

Comment: This question is not completely clear: can you post an example of one of the times from the list? Is the time represented by a string, or is it another type of object?

Comment: Maybe this related discussion will answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms

Comment: The only source I know for that format of date is Excel for the Mac. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180162, even though it's wrong about the start date for the 1900 based dates.

Comment: I just edited to give an example

Comment: Your example is inconsistent with your description of the format.

Comment: How is this inconsistent?

Comment: And the time in the list is a float

Comment: There is no way to get that date and time from the number of seconds you've specified. Just for starters, taking the number mod 60 yields 28 and not 30.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `datetime` and `timedelta` classes for this kind of thing.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date = datetime(1904,1,1) # January 1st, 1904 at midnight

delta = timedelta(seconds = 10000000)

newdate = date + delta
```

`newdate` will evaulate to `datetime.datetime(1904, 4, 26, 17, 46, 40)`, which is April 26, 1904,

Docs on these classes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: The technique is perfect, the details are not - the question specified *1904*, not *1901*.

Comment: Whoops, fixing that now.

Comment: I'm a little confused on this. I thought timedelta gives the time between two different times, what is this timedelta giving the time between? Sorry, this might be simple. I'm still really new to python. I also edited my question to give an example of one of the times. They are in seconds, so would i put that time in timedelta(seconds = data_seconds)?

Comment: I just tried 
    for data_seconds in time:  
        date = datetime(1904,1,1)
        delta = timedelta(seconds = data_seconds)
        newdate = date + delta
    print newdate
and it gave me the wrong date. It gave me 18 days ahead and several hours ahead. I tried manually putting in the first time from the time list and it gave me the right date but about 16 hours ahead.

Comment: I just realized this is the Mac Timestamp if that means anything useful.

Comment: I got it to work! 

I just had to do date = datetime(1904,1,1,5,26,02)

I think the extra times are because of different timezones, leap seconds and leap years. I'm not sure exactly, but using this date made everything work perfectly.

Comment: @jakeowen is the timezone you're working with one of those ones that had an oddball number of minutes offset in the distant past? Otherwise it doesn't explain the unusual starting time you're using - leap seconds wouldn't account for it.

Comment: @MarkRansom It might be offset by an oddball number of minutes. I'd like to look more into this but don't have the time to right now. the datetime I used worked for all the times in the list, so I'm content. Once I finish this project I will look more into why this odd number of seconds makes it works.