# Python: Convert subtracted unix time into hours/mins/seconds

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have received three different unixtimes

```
lastSeen = 1416248381 
firstSeen = 1416248157
```

and the last one is lastSeen - firstSeen:

```
duration = 224
```

Now, I can convert lastSeen and firstSeen into a datetime no problem. But I am having trouble with the duration.

I am unsure how to convert the duration into something like minutes/seconds. Does anyone have any idea if this can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Time Seconds to h:m:s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms)

Comment: Not sure if duplicate because Unixtime - Unixtime doesn't automatically mean it is in seconds, does it?

Comment: For me, it does. Otherwise, what 224 is? seconds, minutes, hours, milliseconds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert your seconds to Hours&Minutes and you can do it using **datetime**

```
import datetime

lastSeen = 1416248381 
firstSeen = 1416248157
duration = lastSeen - firstSeen

str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=duration))
```

The ouput will be: `'0:03:44'`

Without the `str()` function you'll have: `datetime.timedelta(0, 224)`

---

Using **time**

```
import time

time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(duration))
```

The ouput will be: `'0:03:44'`