# Covert seconds to minutes in python django

Tags: python, django, datetime, unix-timestamp

Hi I have a database column named total time which is the difference between two timestamps in seconds format. How can I convert it into minutes using python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Time Seconds to h:m:s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms)

Answer (score 1):

```
seconds = 12345
minutes= float(seconds)/60
avg_minutes = seconds // 60
print minutes
print avg_minutes
import datetime
formatedtime = datetime.timedelta(seconds=94513)
print str(formatedtime)
```

Comment: I've tried this. But for example I've seconds = -897 and when I do this method I get minutes = -15, instead of exact minutes(-14.95)

Comment: Okay that works :) How can I convert it into `hour:minute:second` format other than just the integer result?