# Add hours to timestamps in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, time

I am trying to add `hours` to specific values in a `pandas df` so that they are consistent.

For the `df` below I want to add `24 hours` to the first value.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'time' : ['3:00:00','27:30:00','28:00:00'],               
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I'm using this at the moment.

```
df['time'].iloc[0] = df['time'].iloc[0] + pd.Timedelta(hours=24)
```

But it produces:

```
              time
0  1 days 03:00:00
1         27:30:00
2         28:00:00
```

My intended output is:

```
              time
0         27:00:00
1         27:30:00
2         28:00:00
```

Comment: What dtype is `time`? If it's `timedelta` I'm surprised the others aren't displaying like that

Comment: Take look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134971/python-format-timedelta-greater-than-24-hours-for-display-only-containing-hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First this is not time delta , if you doing the `df.applymap(type)` after the output, you will see the first one is time object, all other should be str.

I can only come out this in my mind

```
df1=df.time.str.split(':',expand=True)
df1.iloc[0,0]=str(int(df1.iloc[0,0])+24)
df1
Out[63]: 
    0   1   2
0  27  00  00
1  27  30  00
2  28  00  00
df1.apply(':'.join,1)# you can add `to_frame('Time') ` as the end 
Out[64]: 
0    27:00:00
1    27:30:00
2    28:00:00
dtype: object
```