# How to counting time in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-database

I have table like this:

```
id | name | time     |
1  | aaaa | 00:36:00 |
2  | aaaa | 01:00:00 |
3  | cccc | 00:10:00 |
4  | bbbb | 00:30:00 |
5  | cccc | 00:30:00 |
```

How can I count the time grouped for each name in Django like this:

```
name | time     |
aaaa | 01:36:00 |
bbbb | 00:30:00 |
cccc | 00:40:00 |
```

It is possible in Django ?? 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the grouping([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses)) by exact time, then you can simple aggregate like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Model.objects.all().values("time").annotate(Count("id")).order_by()
```

---

То aggregate `DateTimeField` and `TimeField` we can use also [**`Trunc`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc)[(Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) function. Truncates a date up to a significant component.

> class Trunc(expression, kind, output_field=None, tzinfo=None,
> is_dst=None, **extra)

**Trunc** takes a single expression, representing a **DateField**, **TimeField**, or **DateTimeField**, a kind representing a date or time part, and an output_field that’s either `DateTimeField()`, `TimeField()`, or `DateField()`.

Specific for TimeField use `TruncHour`, `TruncMinute` or `TruncSecond` see [**Django Docs**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#timefield-truncation) - Usage example:

> ```
> >>> from datetime import date, datetime
> >>> from django.db.models import Count
> >>> from django.db.models.functions import (
> ...     TruncDate, TruncDay, TruncHour, TruncMinute, TruncSecond,
> ... )
> >>> from django.utils import timezone
> >>> import pytz
> >>> start1 = datetime(2014, 6, 15, 14, 30, 50, 321, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
> >>> Experiment.objects.create(start_datetime=start1,start_date=start1.date())
> >>> melb = pytz.timezone('Australia/Melbourne')
> >>> Experiment.objects.annotate(
> ...     date=TruncDate('start_datetime'),
> ...     day=TruncDay('start_datetime', tzinfo=melb),
> ...     hour=TruncHour('start_datetime', tzinfo=melb),
> ...     minute=TruncMinute('start_datetime'),
> ...     second=TruncSecond('start_datetime'),
> ... ).values('date', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second').get()
> {'date': datetime.date(2014, 6, 15),
>  'day': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 16, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Australia/Melbourne' AEST+10:00:00 STD>),
>  'hour': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 16, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Australia/Melbourne' AEST+10:00:00 STD>),
>  'minute': 'minute': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 15, 14, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>),
>  'second': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 15, 14, 30, 50, tzinfo=<UTC>)
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to check it tomorrow.

Comment: @mir_kol, to make the grouping by exact time use this: `Model.objects.all().values("time").annotate(Count("id")).order_by()`. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without looking into your model, but I'm quite sure you can do something like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum


MyModel.objects.filter(...).annotate(time_sum=Sum("time"))
```

Take a look at [Django's aggregate documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/).

Comment: Yes, my example was very general but your method works well... almost. Time is presented in decimal format - example '19000.000000' and it is 02:30:00. I was try to convert like there [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087209/converting-decimal-time-hh-hhh-into-hhmmss-in-python) but it doesn't work ... Have all time something like this... 19000:00:00

Comment: Hm... actually it counting but how? or how to convert it to time format?? **Examples:** 1. 01:45:00, 00:40:00 - should be 02:25:00 but is 18500.000000 ; 2. 00:30:00, 01:15:00, 00:45:00, 00:40:00 should be 03:10:00 but is 23000.000000