# How to change an set of numbers to time [Python]

Tags: python, time

New to programming so really any help is good help haha. So my question is if I take in a number ex. 738218 (any number will do) How can I convert it to hours, minutes, seconds, (ex. 19 hours, 36 minutes, 26 seconds). I have tried some examples I have found but I keep getting errors. This is what I have right now.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import time
sec = input('Enter a number to covert to a formal timestap: ')
hours = sec/12 `enter code here`
minutes = sec/60
time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(sec))
print(time.strtime)
```

Comment: ...And what sort of time does the input number represent?

Comment: Why don't you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/775095/3888543. Check the answer from SilentGhost

Comment: @TigerhawekT3 input reps the seconds that will be converted to a time stamp formate.

Comment: `seconds / 12` is not going to give you the number of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! I've updated your script and added some notes:

```
seconds = int(input('Enter a number to convert to a formal timestamp: '))
hours = seconds // 3600  # there are 3600 seconds per hour
seconds -= hours * 3600  # don't double count seconds counted by hours
minutes = seconds // 60  # there are 60 seconds per minute
seconds -= minutes * 60  # don't double count seconds counted by minutes
time_string = "{}:{}:{}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
print(time_string)
```

going through some of the lines individually:

```
seconds = int(input('Enter a number to convert to a formal timestamp: '))
```

I assume here that you are working in Python 3. If so, `input` is exactly what we want. If you are in Python 2, however, `input` does something slightly related and what we really want is something else - `raw_input`. `raw_input` was renamed `input` when the move was made from 2 to 3. Either way, we pass whatever is input by the user to the `int` function and convert it to an integer value.

```
time_string = "{}:{}:{}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

`"{}:{}:{}"` is a format string. You can read more about them [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings). The pairs of curly brackets are each placeholders for the arguments passed to the `format` method; the first brackets get replaced with the first argument `hours`, the second pair gets replaced with the second argument `minutes`, and so on.

If you are in Python 2, the code won't quite work as specified. Luckily, most of them can be backported to Python 2 by importing from the `__future__` module; the only manual change would be switching `input` to `raw_input` in this case. Here's the same code, in Python 2:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

seconds = int(raw_input('Enter a number to convert to a formal timestamp: '))
hours = seconds // 3600  # there are 3600 seconds per hour
seconds -= hours * 3600  # don't double count seconds counted by hours
minutes = seconds // 60  # there are 60 seconds per minute
seconds -= minutes * 60  # don't double count seconds counted by minutes
time_string = "{}:{}:{}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
print(time_string)
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot! This does clear it up for me! and yes to clear up I am using Python 3. Cheer mate! much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
t = time.time()
d = datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
print d.hour, d.minute, d.second
```