# Python 3.x - Output time taken to execute an operation as DD:HH:MM:SS.SSS

Tags: python-3.x, time

In Python 3.x I want to measure the time it takes to execute an operation and print it in the format DD:HH:MM:SS.SSS (pref with the decimals to include milliseconds). Looking around I couldn't find specifically what I am after in this case on the internet.

My code looks like the following at the moment:

```
import time

t = time.time()
# perform an operation
t = time.time() - t
print('Elapsed time: ' + str(t))
```

Obviously I am getting everything in seconds and i can't quite get how to use the formatting function on variable **t** to get exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this might help: [Python Time Seconds to h:m:s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms)

You can do something similar, but with days included.