# Covert time.time() seconds into current time with format hh:mm:ss in python

Tags: python

As part of the assignment, I am asked to find current time from total number of seconds passed since 1st Jan 1970. I know we can use `time.time()` to get the seconds but I am having trouble getting into current time.

Attached is the code I have so far.

```
import time
a=time.time()
hours= (a)//3600
minutes=(a-hours*3600)/60
second=a%60
print(hours,"h",minutes,"m",second,"s")
```

Please advise.

Comment: try DateTime module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Time Seconds to h:m:s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms)

Answer (score 3):

```
import time
current_time = time.ctime(int(time.time()))
print ("current_time:") + str(current_time)
```

output: Thu, 28 Jun 2012 07:10:11 GMT

for only time use this:

```
 import time
 current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime(time.time()))
 print("current_time:") + str(current_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for overall time passed since 1970 in HH:MM:SS format  you can try this

```
import time
t=time.time()
print "total second from 1970 :" ,t
m, s = divmod(t, 60)
h, m = divmod(m, 60)
print "Overall time passed since 1970: ","%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)
```

And you are just looking for current time in HH.MM.SS, use strftime like this.

```
from datetime import datetime
t = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print "Current Time is :",t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
current_time = time.ctime()
print("current time is:",current_time[11:19])
```