# Issue with converting seconds to hh:mm:ss with large numbers in Python

Tags: python, time, formatting, numbers, sys

The input I get the user to enter is seconds. Most of the time I am able to convert my input to the hh:mm:ss format but when the numbers get a bit larger I seem to run into some issues. For example when I input 900, I get a result of 01:15:-100. I especially don't want negatives and only want two digests (no decimals either) per each number. Not sure if I have gone wrong on my math.

```
if sys.argv[1] == "raceTime":
n = int(sys.argv[2])
if n < 60:
    s = format(number, '0>2.0f')
    print("{}:{}:{}".format(00, 00, s))
else:
    n = int (sys.argv[2])/60
    m =n//1
    h = min//10
    s = (n - h - m)*100
    second = format(s,'0>2.0f')
    minute = format(m, '0>2.0f')
    hour = format(h, '0>2.0f')
    print("{}:{}:{}".format(hour, minute, second))
```

Comment: Multiply the 0.25 * 100 to get 25.  int(1.0) to get 1

Comment: See http://pyformat.info

Comment: Ok this worked great thanks! My only other question is that now when I input larger numbers, like 900 for example, I get strange results. For example: 01:15:-100. How do I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Time Seconds to h:m:s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms)

Answer (score 2):

Use proper [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
second = format(sec, '02.0f')  # etc.
```

or just

```
print("{:02.0f}:{:02.0f}:{:02.0f}".format(hour, min, sec))
# f -> float, 02 -> 2 places before (0-padded), .0 -> 0 places after point
```