# In Julia Convert Elapsed Time to Hours:Minutes:Seconds

Tags: julia

Converting seconds to Hours:Minutes:Seconds has been answered a number of ways for Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds/775075#775075).

How would one do this in Julia?

Comment: There are sooooo many ways to do this.  This [_Introducing Julia_](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Working_with_dates_and_times) WikiBook shows some nice tools for the job.

Comment: See also https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-convert-period-in-milisecond-to-minutes-seconds-hour-etc/2423

Comment: I'm surprised how there's no built-in formatting provided for time deltas.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thanks for the link.

Comment: @crstnbr Thanks for the link.

Comment: @niczky12 Would crstnbr's answer below be built-in formatting for time deltas in your opinion?

Comment: Canonicalize is a good option, but you can't format it as far as I know. I would expect to be able to do something like: `format(my_time_delta, "h m s")` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

This code follows Brandon Rhodes answer in Python at the link in the original question.  It answers the original question.

**Advantage**: Simplicity.

**Disadvantage**: For long simulation runs the output will not be formatted as nicely as the method given after this one.

```
using Printf

start = time()
sleep(65.129)  # 65.129 seconds
elapsed = time() - start

(minutes, seconds) = fldmod(elapsed, 60)
(hours, minutes) = fldmod(minutes, 60)

@printf("%02d:%02d:%0.2f", hours, minutes, seconds)

"""========== The expected output is ==========
00:01:5.16
"""
```

**Method 2**:

@crstnbr solves a similar problem with the `canonacalize` function. I do not see it in the Julia 1.0.0 documentation, but I found it in the Julia source as linked [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/c44644442949238da70670b547312ca1ae9a9c7d/stdlib/Dates/src/periods.jl).

It has the neat property of gracefully handling both short and long elapsed time periods.

**Advantage**: Provides a useful format for long elapsed times.

**Disadvantage**: Does not seem to be in the current Julia 1.0.0 documentation, may be hard to remember.

```
julia> start = now(); sleep(1.23); elapsed = now() - start;
julia> canonicalize(Dates.CompoundPeriod(elapsed))
1 second, 246 milliseconds

julia> canonicalize(Dates.CompoundPeriod(elapsed*1000000))
2 weeks, 10 hours, 6 minutes, 40 seconds
```

If you are doing long simulations, that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not really what you asked for, but maybe still useful:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> start = now(); sleep(1.23); elapsed = now() - start;

julia> canonicalize(Dates.CompoundPeriod(elapsed))
1 second, 231 milliseconds
```

See https://discourse.julialang.org/t/conversion-and-formatting-of-dates-timeperiod/15063.

Comment: Is using `now()` considered more "Julian" than `time()`, or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: `now()` returns a `Dates.DateTime` and is only avaible after `using Dates`. `time()` returns an integer (microseconds). In that sense `time()` is more simple/low-level.

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks!