# Convert numpy array of seconds to minutes and seconds

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, datetime, timedelta, divmod

Here is a good stack overflow question on how to go from seconds to hours, minutes and seconds: [How do I convert seconds to hours, minutes and seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/how-do-i-convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds)

However, I couldn't find how to convert a numpy array of seconds to minutes:seconds.
I have a plot with it's ticks being seconds, so I want to convert that min and sec.

## Data

```
# example data
tick_sec = np.array([-5., 0., 5., 10., 15., 20., 25., 30., 35., 40., 55., 60., 65., 70.])
# origin of data: tick_sec = ax.get_xticks()
```

## timedelta attempt

```
import datetime

datetime.timedelta(seconds=tick_sec)
```

Gives:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-cc4fdae20757> in <module>
      1 import datetime
      2 
----> 3 datetime.timedelta(seconds=tick_sec)

TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: numpy.ndarray
```

## divmod attempt (working)

```
def sec_to_minsec(sec_arr):
    tick_min, tick_sec = divmod(sec_arr, 60)  # returns 2 numpy.ndarray
    print(type(tick_min))

    tick_m_s = np.empty([tick_min.size], dtype=(np.str, 8))  # init empty string array
    for i, min_sec in enumerate(zip(tick_min, tick_sec)):  # loop over 2 arrays
        tick_m_s[i] = f"{int(min_sec[0]):02d}:{int(min_sec[1]):02d}"  # add 0 before min and sec

    return tick_m_s

sec_to_minsec(tick_sec)
```

Output:

```
array(['-1:55', '00:00', '00:05', '00:10', '00:15', '00:20', '00:25',
       '00:30', '00:35', '00:40', '00:55', '01:00', '01:05', '01:10'],
      dtype='<U8')
```

Works, but I feel this could be more efficient? Also, it gives a weird output for negative time (although that's not of concern for my current problem)

## System

- Python 3.6 in a Jupyter Notebook environment

## Question

Is there a better/efficient/shorter code way to do my `divmod` attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is more efficient or not, but you can get it done with `timedelta`. Performance is highly dependent on the complete dataset among other things, so you should run some tests to determine what is really best in your situation.

For example:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np

tick_sec = np.array([-5., 0., 5., 10., 15., 20., 25., 30., 35., 40., 55., 60., 65., 70.])

tick_hms = np.array([str(timedelta(seconds=s)) for s in tick_sec])
print(tick_hms)
# ['-1 day, 23:59:55' '0:00:00' '0:00:05' '0:00:10' '0:00:15' '0:00:20' '0:00:25' '0:00:30' '0:00:35' '0:00:40' '0:00:55' '0:01:00' '0:01:05' '0:01:10']
```