# How to convert seconds into minutes or hours in discord.py command on cooldown error

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx,error):
  if isinstance(error , commands.CommandOnCooldown):
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}**hold your horses buddy <:iac_namaste:841266597318361098>**')
    await ctx.send('Try again in {:2f}s'.format(error.retry_after))
```

I have added cooldowns on one of my command for 20 min

```
@commands.cooldown(1 , 1200, type=commands.BucketType.user)
```

and it is working fine but I'm not getting the output in min or hr format

[image]

I want it to send something like try again in 20 min , and also show how many min's left

Comment: To get minutes from seconds you have to divide the seconds by 60.

Comment: but how can I do that in a string

Comment: `await ctx.send('Try again in {:2f} minutes'.format(error.retry_after / 60))`. I assume that `error.retry_after` is a number, otherwise you will have to use `float` to convert it to a number first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert seconds to hours, minutes and seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/how-do-i-convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds)

Comment: @Matthias oh thanks for that 
```await ctx.send('Try again in {:2f}m'.format((error.retry_after)/60))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to just use the new [discord timestamp format](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/blob/ff4d9d8ea6493405a8823492338880c47fb02996/docs/Reference.md#timestamp-styles)

```py
import time  # Add this to the top

# Then in the error handler
await ctx.send('Try again in <t:{}:R>'.format(int(time.time() + error.retry_after)))
```

Comment: waoo , thanks buddy , now it's looking a whole lot better