# Discord.py Cooldown in Seconds

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Well, I have a command with a cooldown. It shows the cooldown in seconds, but I want it to be in
hours:minutes:seconds.
Since I'm still very new to Python. I need a little help.
This is my Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("User existiert nicht!")
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        msg = f'**Du bist in einem Cooldown** Versuch es in {round(error.retry_after)} Sekunden erneut.'
        await ctx.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Suggested related question which very much applies to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/how-do-i-convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds)

But, adapted to your use case with just a little bit of math (no extra `import`s):

```
msg = f'**Du bist in einem Cooldown** Versuch es in {error.retry_after // (60 * 60):02d}:{(error.retry_after // 60) % 60:02d}:{error.retry_after % 60:02d} erneut.'
```

Would result in

```
"**Du bist in einem Cooldown** Versuch es in 34:17:36 erneut."
```

with `error.retry_after == 123456`.

Assuming `error.retry_after` is an integer. If it's not, cast it to an integer first and store it in another variable that is then used for the math.

Comment: ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'

Comment: Either follow the last paragraph of my answer or change the format code (```:02d```) to ```:02.0f``` which will truncate the decimal part of a floating point number string.