# Plot datetime object as continuous variable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Need a hand with some plotting on Seaborn (sns). I'm using Python 3.11.4 on Jupyter Notebooks v6.5.4 via the Anaconda Navigator v.23.7.2, on MacOS.

I have a data frame of which a portion is shown below. Behaviour was pre-converted to numeric values using `pandas.DataFrame.replace` but the issue comes with the Time variable:

```
data { 'Time' : ['12:27:00', '12:27:00', '12:12:00', '11:55:00', '12:00:00', '12:11:00', '15:28:00','15:20:00','15:40:00','12:10:00']
'Behaviour' : [2,1,1,0,2,0,0,1,1,2]
}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

When I try to plot this using `sns.scatterplot(x="Time",y="Behaviour")` the `float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'datetime.time'` error message comes up.

However, I don't want to convert it to a string -- I tried that and while I did get a plot, the x-axis labels were all squashed, and I couldn't change the ticks because Time was now a string. As such, I want to be able to plot Time as a continuous variable. Converting the data frame column to numeric returns all values as `NaN`.

Is there any way to plot Time as a continuous variable?

Comment: Convert the values to a timedelta (with the smallest value being the subtrahend), and then to total_seconds, which will result in an integer. Plot the values against total_seconds, and then reformat the xtick labels with something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/775049/7758804

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work better if you convert 'Time' to a datetime?

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

Comment: It did, thank you! Didn't realise Excel would read the time values as a series, until I realised the values had custom formatting in Excel rather than datetime. Importing from a CSV followed by this method made it work. Now just to reformat the xtick labels...

Comment: if you are reading these from a csv check out the date processing with the parse_dates param in pd.read_csv():  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html