# does python multiplicative expression evaluates faster if finds a zero?

Tags: python, optimization, math, evaluation

suppose i a have a multiplicative expression with lots of multiplicands (small expressions)

```
expression = a*b*c*d*....*w
```

where for example c is (x-1), d is (y**2-16), k is (x*y-60).....   x,y are numbers

and i know that c,d,k,j maybe zero

Does the order i write the expression matters for faster evaluation?

Is it better to write c*d*k*j....*w or python will evaluate all expression no matter the order i write?

Comment: How to explain Baldur's last timing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python v2.6.5 does not check for zero values.

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 0
    return a * b * c

>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  4          12 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (c)

  5          18 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             21 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             24 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             25 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
             28 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

**Update:** I tested [Baldur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264345/does-python-multiplicative-expression-evaluates-faster-if-finds-a-zero/3264701#3264701)'s expressions, and Python can and will optimize code that involve constant expressions. The *weird* is that `test6` isn't optimized.

```
def test1():
    return 0 * 1

def test2():
    a = 1
    return 0 * a * 1

def test3():
    return 243*(5539**35)*0

def test4():
    return 0*243*(5539**35)

def test5():
    return (256**256)*0

def test6():
    return 0*(256**256)

>>> dis.dis(test1) # 0 * 1
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (0)
              3 RETURN_VALUE       

>>> dis.dis(test2) # 0 * a * 1
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  6           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             12 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             13 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             16 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             17 RETURN_VALUE        

>>> dis.dis(test3) # 243*(5539**35)*0
  9           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (243)
              3 LOAD_CONST               5 (104736434394484...681759461305771899L)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 LOAD_CONST               4 (0)
             10 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             11 RETURN_VALUE        

>>> dis.dis(test4) # 0*243*(5539**35)
 12           0 LOAD_CONST               5 (0)
              3 LOAD_CONST               6 (104736433252667...001759461305771899L)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE        

>>> dis.dis(test5) # (256**256)*0
 15           0 LOAD_CONST               4 (0L)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        

>>> dis.dis(test6) # 0*(256**256)
 18           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 (323170060713110...853611059596230656L)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

In brief, if the expression includes variables, the order doesn't matter. Everything will be evaluated.

Comment: This is for constants, while the question involves multiplying expressions.

Comment: This still involves constant expressions, BTW. :-) I think the right things to compare would be something like (say) x=5; y=12; (x*y-58)*(x*y-59)*(x*y-60) for different orderings of the final expression (but with larger constants).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, come on, doesn't `a * b * c` already demonstrate that? Anyway, I did more combinations. Really, unless I'm missing something, I don't think the compiler will embed code that checks variables for zero values. The generated code is always a series of load, multiply, add, subtract instructions.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. I think you've already demonstrated that Python "will evaluate all expression no matter the order i write". But to answer "Does the order i write the expression matters for faster evaluation?", I still suspect the answer is Yes (possibly not in the way the questioner meant, i.e., even if the generated code is the same), simply because (assuming multiplication is done left to right) multiplying several large constants by 0 should be faster than multiplying ever-increasing constants, and only finally by 0. I've been too lazy to test any of this myself. :p

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, OK, now you're clear :) you mean `0*1*2*3*n` is faster than `1*2*3*n*0`. Yes, probably `multiply` won't actually do the multiplication if an operand is zero, currying a zero from the beginning is better. I answered specifically about dropping  the evaluation once Python encounters a zero, but yeah good point ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to optimize before you benchmark.

With that in mind, it is true that all expressions will be evaluated even if an intermediate term is zero.

Order may still matter. Expressions are [evaluated from left to right](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/evalorder.html). If `a,b,c,...` are very large numbers, they could force Python to allocate a lot of memory, slowing down the calculation before it comes to `j=0`. (If `j=0` came earlier in the expression, then the product would never get as large and no additional memory allocation would be needed).

If, after timing your code with [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) or [cProfile](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-cProfile), you feel this may be your situation, then you could try pre-evaluating `c,d,k,j`, and testing

```
if not all (c,d,k,j):
    expression = 0
else:
    expression = a*b*c*d*....*w
```

Then time this with `timeit` or `cProfile` as well. The only way to really tell if this is useful in your situation is to benchmark.

```
In [333]: import timeit

In [334]: timeit.timeit('10**100*10**100*0')
Out[334]: 1.2021231651306152

In [335]: timeit.timeit('0*10**100*10**100')
Out[335]: 0.13552498817443848
```

Although PyPy is much faster, it does not appear to optimize this either:

```
% pypy-c
Python 2.7.3 (d994777be5ab, Oct 12 2013, 14:13:59)
[PyPy 2.2.0-alpha0 with GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``http://twitpic.com/52ae8f''
>>>> import timeit
>>>> timeit.timeit('10**100*10**100*0')
0.020643949508666992
>>>> timeit.timeit('0*10**100*10**100')
0.003732919692993164
```

Comment: This makes Python seem really stupid.  Shouldn't it catch things like multiplication by zero during the compilation to bytecode and optimize them out?  Is PyPy better at such things?

Comment: @endolith: No, PyPy does not optimize this either. See above.

Comment: But in both your examples the time is reduced by an order of magnitude when you put the 0 in the beginning, right? I guess I've missed something.. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @George: The OP is asking if Python recognizes that 0 times anything is 0 and is thus able to short-circuit the entire calculation and just return 0. If Python did this optimization, then we should expect `10**100*10**100*0` to be evaluated just as fast as `0*10**100*10**100`. Since the timing is clearly different, Python must not be performing this optimization.

Comment: @George: Note that Nick Dandoulakis's answer shows that Python *sometimes* performs this optimization, but sometimes not. Compare `dis.dis(lambda: (256**256*0))` versus `dis.dis(lambda: (100*256**256*0))` for example.

Comment: OK, now it makes sense :) Thanks for the super fast/clear answer!

Answer (score 5):

This is just a quick check in Python 3.1:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('243*325*(5539**35)*0')
0.5147271156311035
>>> timeit.timeit('0*243*325*(5539**35)')
0.153839111328125
```

and this in Python 2.6:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('243*325*(5539**35)*0')
0.72972488403320312
>>> timeit.timeit('0*243*325*(5539**35)')
0.26213502883911133
```

So the order does enter into it.

Also I got this result in Python 3.1:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('(256**256)*0')
0.048995018005371094
>>> timeit.timeit('0*(256**256)')
0.1501758098602295
```

Why on Earth?

Comment: nevermind... http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html?highlight=timeit#timeit.timeit

Comment: The last timing result is due to the limited abilities of CPython's peephole optimizer.  The bytecode for the expression `(256**256)*0` is folded all the way down to the single constant `0`, so your timing doesn't include any arithmetic operations at all.  For the second expression, the `256**256` is folded to a constant, but you're still left with the multiplication by `0`.  I'm guessing this is because the peepholer essentially works left-to-right.

Comment: Try timing with variables not constants

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*9'*6)
0.13404703140258789
>>> timeit.timeit('1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*0'*6)
0.13294696807861328
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably not. Multiplication is one of the cheapest operations of all. If a 0 should be faster then it would be necessary to check for zeros before and that's probably slower than just doing the multiplication.

The fastest solution should be `multiply.reduce()`

Comment: You forget that ints (Python 3.X) and longs (Python 2.X) are variable-length, and multiplication time increases with length. So `0 * huge * huge` will run a lot faster than `huge * huge * 0`