# How to prove that parameter evaluation is "left to right" in Python?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, operator-precedence

For example, in JavaScript we could write a program like this:

```js
var a = 1;
testFunction(++a, ++a, a);
function testFunction(x, y, z){
      document.writeln("<br />x = " + x);
      document.writeln("<br />y = " + y);
      document.writeln("<br />z = " + z);
}
```

and we would get an output:

```
x = 2
y = 3
z = 3
```

This implies that parameters are truly evaluated from left to right in JavaScript. In C we would get output

```
x = 3
y = 3
z = 3
```

I was wondering if we could do the same in Python or is it impossible since it's a pass by value reference language?

I've made a simple program but I don't think that proves anything:

```
x = 2
def f(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)

f(x*2, x*2, x**2)
print(x)
```

```
4 4 4
2
```

Python won't let me do any new assignment within the function parameter when I call it (for example `f(x=4, x, x)` or something like this).

Comment: Actually, in C, you'd get UB (so the output might be different depending on the environment).

Comment: Actually **[Python evaluates expressions L-to-R except for assignments, where the RHS is evaluated before the LHS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288616/is-pythons-order-of-evaluation-of-function-arguments-and-operands-deterministic)**

Comment: "This implies that parameters are truly evaluated from left to right in JavaScript." – No, it implies that for this particular version of this particular implementation in this particular environment on this particular run of this particular code, the arguments were evaluated in such a away that it *appears* that they were evaluated left-to-right. It does not say anything about, for example, a different implementation running on a different Operating System on a different CPU.

Comment: "In C we would get output" – No, we wouldn't. The code you showed has Undefined Behavior in C, which means that the implementation is *literally* allowed to do *anything it wants*. It could print `11 7 5`, it could print `4 4 4`, it could print nothing, it could format your hard drive. All of that would be allowed by the spec.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> def f(x, y): pass
...
>>> f(print(1), print(2))
1
2
```

Comment: Short and simple -- very nice.

Answer (score 4):

Disassemble the function call.

```
>>> def foo():
...   bar(x+1, x+2, x+3)
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (bar)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 BINARY_ADD          
             10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             13 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             16 BINARY_ADD          
             17 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
             20 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             23 BINARY_ADD          
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             27 POP_TOP             
             28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             31 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Wow thats a cool answer but its more like confusing. Is this some kind of general evaluation order of parameters?

Comment: Cant say that this works. Did u foget something to import? I get `NameError: name 'dis' is not defined`

Comment: *I* didn't forget to import it... O.O

Comment: Well i get this `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    dis.dis(foo)
NameError: name 'dis' is not defined` when i type dis.dis(foo). Dont know why.

Comment: even though it's understandeable after a little? thought, explanations would be welcome…

Answer (score 4):

Using Python 3:

```
>>> a = []
>>> f = print(
    a.append(1), a[:],
    a.append(2), a[:],
    a.append(3), a[:]
)
None [1] None [1, 2] None [1, 2, 3]
```

---

Archive:

```
>>> a = []
>>> f = print(a.append(1), a, a.append(2), a, a.append(3), a)
```

Curiously enough (at first), this code produces:

```
None [1, 2, 3] None [1, 2, 3] None [1, 2, 3]
```

However, `dis(f)` makes this clearer:

```
>>> dis(f)

  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print) #Loads the value of 'print' into memory. Precisely, the value is pushed to the TOS (Top of Stack)
    -->       3 LOAD_NAME                1 (a) #Loads the value of object 'a' 
              6 LOAD_ATTR                2 (append) #Loads the append attribute (in this case method)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (1) #Loads the constant 1
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1 #a.append(1) is called
             15 LOAD_NAME                1 (a) #for print(...,a,...)
             18 LOAD_NAME                1 (a) #for the next a.append()
             21 LOAD_ATTR                2 (append) 
             24 LOAD_CONST               1 (2) 
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            1 #a.append(2)
             30 LOAD_NAME                1 (a) 
             33 LOAD_NAME                1 (a) 
             36 LOAD_ATTR                2 (append) 
             39 LOAD_CONST               2 (3) 
             42 CALL_FUNCTION            1 #a.append(3)
             45 LOAD_NAME                1 (a) #loads a to be used thrice by print
             48 CALL_FUNCTION            6 #calls print
             51 PRINT_EXPR                 #prints TOS and clears it
             52 LOAD_CONST               3 (None) #Loads None
             55 RETURN_VALUE             #Returns None
```

The output of `dis(f)` is what we expected - L-to-R evaluation. Essentially, this "discrepancy" is a consequence of `print()` being evaluated last. By then, the value of `a` has changed to `[1, 2, 3]` and the same final object is printed thrice.

If we replace `a` with `a[:]`, we get the expected result.

Comment: @Geo Papas: remmember that, in Python 2, `print` is not a function call.  So use the Python 3 print() function.

Comment: This example is Python 2, check you get the same result using Python 3 (pretty sure you will).

Comment: Sorry but it doesnt work i guess there is a change in python 3. I get output `None [1, 2, 3] None [1, 2, 3] None [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @AnujGupta +1 Very good answer I would accept this but larsmans had a more simple and juicy example. hmm cant i accept 2 answers? :o

Comment: Oh go on, accept his answer... </3. In all seriousness, Larsmans' answer *is* the best :) I'm just glad I learned something here!

Comment: @AnujGupta If u can also explain what this list from dis is would be awesome! i ll edit my question so that it points to your answer as well.

Comment: `import dis; dis.__doc__` - 'Disassembler of Python byte code into mnemonics.' `dis.dis(object)` is the true representation of what's going on under the hood. I've commented most parts of the `dis` output to make it easier to understand.

Comment: This works under Python 2 if you first use `from __future__ import print_function` +1, good answer

Answer (score 1):

This shows it as well IMHO:

```
>>> '{} {} {}'.format(x,x+1,x+2)
'1 2 3'
```

Edit:

```
>>> def f(t):   return time.time()-t 
...         

>>> t1=time.time(); '{:.4} {:.4} {:.4}'.format(f(t1),f(t1),f(t1))
'5.007e-06 7.868e-06 9.06e-06'
```

Comment: There is nothing is this example to show that `x+2` was not evaluated before `x`.

Answer (score 1):

A custom class can help here:

```
class Tester(object):
    "test object to reveal left to right evaluation"
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __add__(self, value):
        print("adding ", value)
        return Tester(self.value + value)
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)
```

and when run:

```
--> t = Tester(7)
--> t
7
--> t = t + 7
adding  7
--> t
14
--> def blah(a, b, c):
...   print(a, b, c)
... 
--> blah(t+1, t+2, t+3)
adding  1
adding  2
adding  3
15 16 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: left to right

Example:
Since this is a question that always pops in my head when I am doing arithmetic operations (should I convert to float and which number), an example from that aspect is presented:

```
>>> a = 1/2/3/4/5/4/3
>>> a
0
```

When we divide integers, not surprisingly it gets lower rounded.

```
>>> a = 1/2/3/4/5/4/float(3)
>>> a
0.0
```

If we typecast the last integer to float, we will still get zero, since by the time our number gets divided by the float has already become 0 because of the integer division.

```
>>> a = 1/2/3/float(4)/5/4/3
>>> a
0.0
```

Same scenario as above but shifting the float typecast a little closer to the left side.

```
>>> a = float(1)/2/3/4/5/4/3
>>> a
0.0006944444444444445
```

Finally, when we typecast the first integer to float, the result is the desired one, since beginning from the first division, i.e. the leftmost one, we use floats.

Extra 1: If you are trying to answer that to improve arithmetic evaluation, you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264345)

Extra 2: Please be careful of the following scenario:

```
>>> a = float(1/2/3/4/5/4/3)
>>> a
0.0
```