# Changing variable order in Python comma-separated multiple assignment

Tags: python, multiple-assignment

When one uses a multiple assignment in Python, such as

```
a, b, c = b, c, a
```

I've always thought that the relative order of the arguments is irrelevant (as long as one is consistent on both sides), i.e., the result would be the same if one does

```
c, a, b = a, b, c
```

While this appears to be true when `a, b, c` are independent variables, it seems that it may not be true when they are related.

For instance, if we define a node of a linked list as follows:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

and write a function to reverse a linked list in-place:

```
def reverseList(head):
    """
    :type head: ListNode
    :rtype: ListNode
    """
    if head is None:
        return head
    slow = None
    fast = head
    while fast is not None:
        fast.next, slow, fast = slow, fast, fast.next

    return slow
```

then this works fine, for instance:

```
head = ListNode(1)
head.next = ListNode(2)
reverseList(head)
```

However, if we replace the line in the loop with a different assignment ordering:

```
fast, fast.next, slow = fast.next, slow, fast
```

then we get an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

In the second (last) iteration, both `fast` and `slow` are not `None` and `fast.next` is `None`, but I still don't understand why this causes an error? Shouldn't the multiple assignments be done in parallel?

More generally, when and when not could one change the order of a multiple assignment statement without affecting the result?

Edit: I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288616/is-pythons-order-of-evaluation-of-function-arguments-and-operands-deterministic), and while it is related I still don't get how the answers there help to explain my issue. I would appreciate any elaboration on my case.

Comment: Please note that your `a b c` examples are *not* equivalent.

Comment: @wim I've read the marked question, and while it is related I still don't get how the answers there help to explain my issue. I would appreciate any elaboration on my case.

Comment: @Prune Sorry, thanks for catching the typo! I've fixed the question.

Comment: The order of evaluation in an assignment statement is well-defined, is **not** done in parallel, and the rules are clearly described in the linked answer. Could you explain what questions remain that are not already answered?

Comment: @p-value: the specific reference is where you're *mutating* one of the arguments during the assignment phase; read that part again and see how it applies to your example.  That's where you run into trouble in your linked list: you mutate `fast` before you alter the *old* `fast.next`.

Comment: @Prune Thanks; after reading the docs I think that makes sense now. To summarize, the evaluation is always from left to right, but the right-hand-side is always evaluated first, which still makes the multiple assignment different than sequential assignments.

Comment: also check `dis.dis` for more fun and excitement!