# variable assignment order in python comma-separated multiple assignment

Tags: python, multiple-assignment

I apologise since this question has been asked before, but I did not really understand the answer and the comments, but I do not have enough reputation to comment on those threads...

[Changing variable order in Python comma-separated multiple assignment [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047077/changing-variable-order-in-python-comma-separated-multiple-assignment)

Essentially I do not understand what order python does variable assignment when you assign multiple of them in the same line.

For example:

```
a, b, = [2,3,4,5], [1]
a[1:], a, b = b, a[1:], a
print("a = ", a)
print("b = ", b)
```

returns

```
a = [3, 4, 5]
b = [2, 1]
```

From what I understand, python evaluates the RHS of the assignment statement first, so it evaluates
`b, a[1:], a` to be `1, [3,4,5], [2,3,4,5]`.
But this doesn't make sense because `b = [2,1]`.

Furthermore, if I were to instead do `a, b, a[1:] = a[1:], a, b`, it will instead return

```
a = [3, 1]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So it seems the order does matter, and it seems to go from left to right.

However if I were to do `b, a[1:], a = a, b, a[1:]`, it returns

```
a = [3, 4, 5]
b = [2, 1]
```

Why does it not evaluate `b = a` first which should return `[2,3,4,5]`?

Would really appreciate if anyone could explain this to me...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understand Python swapping: why is a, b = b, a not always equivalent to b, a = a, b?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152730/understand-python-swapping-why-is-a-b-b-a-not-always-equivalent-to-b-a-a)