# Division in Python 3 gives different result than in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

In the following code, I want to calculate the percent of G and C characters in a sequence.  In Python 3 I correctly get `0.5`, but on Python 2 I get `0`.  Why are the results different?

```
def gc_content(base_seq):
    """Return the percentage of G and C characters in base_seq"""
    seq = base_seq.upper()
    return (seq.count('G') + seq.count('C')) / len(seq)

gc_content('attacgcg')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/` is a different operator in Python 3; in Python 2 `/` alters behaviour when applied to 2 integer operands and returns the result of a floor-division instead:

```
>>> 3/2   # two integer operands
1
>>> 3/2.0 # one operand is not an integer, float division is used
1.5
```

Add:

```
from __future__ import division
```

to the top of your code to make `/` use float division in Python 2, or use `//` to force Python 3 to use integer division:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 3/2    # even when using integers, true division is used
1.5
>>> 3//2.0 # explicit floor division
1.0
```

Using either of these techniques works in Python 2.2 or newer. See [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) for the nitty-gritty details of why this was changed.

Comment: Is that a "best-practice" or gnibbler's first solution below "better?"

Comment: This is best-practice. The work-around to use `float()` will work too, but it is basically a hack to avoid the issue. `from __future__ import division` is the correct way of handling this as Python 3 switches behaviour.

Comment: Can `from __future__ import division` be used when using ipython?

Comment: Yes, it works in ipython; it works in the standard Python console as well.

Answer (score 2):

In python2.x `/` performs integers division.

```
>>> 3/2
1
```

To get desired result you can change either one of the operands to a float using `float()`:

```
>>> 3/2.      #3/2.0
1.5
>>> 3/float(2)
1.5
```

or use `division` from `__future__`:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 3/2
1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python2 `/` is integer division when the numerator and denominator are both `int`, you need to make sure to force floating point division

eg.

```
return (seq.count('G') + seq.count('C')) / float(len(seq))
```

alternatively, you can put

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of the file