# In python, how do I preserve decimal places in numbers?

Tags: python

I'd like to pass numbers around between functions, while preserving the decimal places for the numbers.

I've discovered that if I pass  a float like '10.00' in to a function, then the decimal places don't get used. This messes an operation like calculating percentages.

For example, x * (10 / 100) will always return 0.
But if I manage to preserve the decimal places, I end up doing x * (10.00 / 100). This returns an accurate result.

I'd like to have a technique that enables consistency when I'm working with numbers that decimal places that can hold zeroes.

Comment: Also, I think you're wrong. If you pass a float, it will be used like a float. IMO you are passing an int there.

Comment: As soon as there is one float involved Python 2 will do an float division, so you should explicitly specify the `.0` when calling the function. Python 3 always performs a float division unless explicitly told otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Division in python for `float` and `int` works differently, take a look at this question and it's answers: [Python division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division).

Moreover, if you are looking for a solution to format a decimal floating point of your figures into string, you might need to use `%f`.

**Python**

```
# '1.000000'
"%f" % (1.0)

# '1.00'
"%.2f" % (1.0)

# '  1.00'
"%6.2f" % (1.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
10 / 100
```

you are performing integer division. That's because both operands are integers. The result is `0`.

If you want to perform floating point division, make one of the operands be a floating point value. For instance:

```
10.0 / 100
```

or

```
float(10) / 100
```

Do beware also that

```
10.0 / 100
```

results in a binary floating point value and binary floating data types cannot represent the true result value of `0.1`. So if you want to represent the result accurately you may need to use a decimal data type. The `decimal` module has the functionality needed for that.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.x will use integer division when dividing two integers unless you explicitly tell it to do otherwise. Two integers in --> one integer out.

Python 3 onwards will return, to quote PEP 238 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/ a reasonable approximation of the result of the division approximation, i.e. it will perform a floating point division and return the result without rounding.

To enable this behaviour in earlier version of Python you can use:

```
from __future__ import division
```

At the very top of the module, this should get you the consistent results you want.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `decimal` module. Each number knows how many significant digits it has.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to preserve significant digits, the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module is has everything you need. Example:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> num = Decimal('10.00')
>>> num
Decimal('10.00')
>>> num / 10
Decimal('1.00')
```

Comment: A more dramatic example: `str(Decimal(time.time()))`

Comment: @bahmait true, that's very interesting. The point I was trying to convey though was that it maintains a concept of significant digits. i.e if you enter `10.00` it distinguishes it from `10.0` or `10.000`. Any float converted to Decimal directly can give you a uselessly long result as you pointed out. Try `Decimal(0.1)`!