# Read in a file that has multiple grades, each separated by a comma, and prints out the computed average

Tags: python, average

QUESTION: Complete the following program, which reads in a file that has multiple grades, each separated by a comma, and prints out the computed average. That is, write the functions `getGrades():` and `calculateAverage():`

```
def main():
  grades = getGrades()   #get the file name containing the grades
                         #and return the contents of the file
  avg = calculateAverage(grades) #separate the grades into numbers and compute
                         #the average
  print("The calculated average is:", avg)
main()
```

I have inserted the given function and wrote a new program, but I am little bit confused, also I am getting an error. Please help!

```
def getGrades():
  filename = input("Please enter a file name: ")
  openfile = open(filename, "r")
  readfile = openfile.readlines()

  return readfile

def calculateAverage(n):
  totalGrades = []

  for i in (n):
    Split = list(map(int, i.split(",")))
    totalGrades += Split

  avg = sum(totalGrades)/float(len(totalGrades))

  return avg

def main():
  grades = getGrades()                  
  avg = calculateAverage(grades) 
  print("The calculated average is:", avg)
main()
```

Comment: Smells homework. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: error: readfile is not defined

Comment: Yes, it is a homework problem. But I am excessively trying myself. I just need little help.

Comment: In your getgrades function you should put the grades in a list and pass that to the other function

Comment: If you're only entering a filename (and not a file path), the "open" function call is expecting the file to be in the same directory as your python script.  Otherwise, you need to pass a path to the file.  Are your script/file saved in the same directory?

Comment: In your `calculateAverage` function you pass argument `n` and then you try to use the variable name of the previous function (`readfile`). Change `readfile` to whatever you pass as argument (here `n`). Besides that, your program has more problems but I guess your immediate problem is now solved, the rest are part of your HW.

Comment: modified my program according to your comments. Getting an error: "nsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'float'"

Comment: python 3.3                          .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `calculateAverage()` function, you pass the argument `n` but for the `for` loop you use the local variable name `readfile` of function `getGrades()`.

Also, the result of [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) is a list of strings. To convert them to integers to perform the summations you can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map). `map` returns an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results.

To remove newline and other whitespace from the lines you read you can use [`rstrip()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-newline-in-python).

Finally, to perform a floating point division if both your arguments are integers you have to transform one of the two to a `float`. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division).

The final program looks like this:

```
def getGrades():
  filename = input("Please enter a file name: ")
  openfile = open(filename, "r")
  readfile = openfile.readlines()

  return readfile

def calculateAverage(n):
  total_grades = []
  for i in (n):
    line_grade = list(map(int, i.rstrip().split(",")))
    total_grades += line_grade
  avg = sum(total_grades)/float(len(total_grades))
  return avg

def main():
  grades = getGrades()                  
  avg = calculateAverage(grades) 
  print("The calculated average is:", avg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

If you run this with a test file with contents:
5,10,15,20
you get:

```
>>> 
Please enter a file name: test.txt
The calculated average is: 12.5
>>>
```

`calculateAverage(n)` without `map()` and with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) could be:

```
def calculateAverage(n):
  total_grades = []
  for i in (n):
    line_grade = i.rstrip().split(",")
    line_grade = [int(x) for x in line_grade]
    total_grades += line_grade
  avg = sum(total_grades)/float(len(total_grades))
  return avg
```

Finally you can do it the naive way and have a for loop for converting each element in the list returned by split to integer:

```
def calculateAverage(n):
  total_grades = []
  for i in (n):
    line_grade = i.rstrip().split(",")
    for element in line_grade:
      total_grades.append(int(element))
  avg = sum(total_grades)/float(len(total_grades))
  return avg
```

Comment: Your program gives me an error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.9\n'

Comment: Your program gives me an error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.9\n'

Comment: It was because you didn't remove newline characters - such as `\n` - before adding them to the list. Give it a go now, I have added the `rstrip()` part

Comment: Can you replace `map` with something else? I did not learn that function.

Comment: any alternative for `map`?

Comment: See edits version, I added two more ways to do the same thing.

Comment: If this answer helps you feel free to accept/vote it up