# Python - Divide only worked when used floating point for divisor

Tags: python, floating-point, semantics, integer-division

Why is it that my code only worked when I turned the divisor into a float?

```
a = 50/1000.0*100
```

When I did the below, it returned a 0.

```
a = 50/1000*100
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

50/1000 is 0 in python 2.x because division of integers assumes you want integer results. If you convert either the numerator or denominator to a float you will get the correct behavior. Alternatively you can use

`from __future__ import division`

to get the python 3.x semantics.

Answer (score 2):

When both operands are integers in Python 2, `a/b` is the same as `a//b`, meaning you get integer division. `50 / 1000` is 0 in that case (with a remainder of 50, as you can see from the return value of `divmod(50, 1000)`).

Answer (score 0):

if you use python 2.X above result came's
if use python 3.x result is

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jul 28 2015, 18:24:59) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
>>> a = 50/1000*100
>>> a
5.0
>>> a = 50/1000.0*100
>>> a
5.0
>>>
```