# Python - computed value is always 0.0

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a basic loop as follows:

```
for x in range(81,346):
    print float(((x - 81)/(346-81))*100)
    # DO STUFF
```

The thing is, the output I get is `0.0` for all values. I checked to see that `x-81` is giving the correct output. I also replaced `346-81` as `265`. But for some reason, all output is being given as `0.0`.
Any suggestions as to what is going wrong?

Comment: You are seeing this problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division. Use floats as intermediate results to fix the issue - `print float(((x - 81.0)/(346-81))*100)`

Comment: Thanks @NikolaDimitroff. Don't know how I missed that one.

Comment: FYI this behavior has changed in Python3.   Python3 does float division by default.  It also introduced integer division operator `//`

Answer (score 4):

You are performing integer division. Change `81` to `81.0` or cast the numerator or denominator to `float`.

Comment: So typecasting doesn't work?  
`float(346-81)` would also work?

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly typecasting will also work, just make sure to cast before the division happens.

Answer (score 3):

Python 2 uses integer division on integers. It was a bad idea and Python 3 fixed it. To have the (better) behaviour from *future*, put this in the beginning of your py file:

```
from __future__ import division
```