# Python function for sums of integers

Tags: python, function, sum

Wrote a python program that added up numbers from 1 to a given number using the Gauss equation. It worked for 100 and 10 but when I do 3 it says the sum is 4 instead of 6. The equation works out in my head, did I mess up the code?

```
def numberSum(num): 

    nim = int(num)
    num = (nim/2)*(nim+1)
    return num    

print numberSum(raw_input())
```

Comment: This is probably an integer division problem - try `nim/2.0`

Comment: No, don't use 2.0. Multiply before dividing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from __future__ import division

def number_sum(num):
    """
    Return sum of 1 .. num
    """
    return num * (num + 1) // 2

num = int(raw_input(": "))
print(number_sum(num))
```

Things I changed:

- `number_sum` should not be responsible for type-casting input; if it expects a number, you should give it *some kind* of number, not a string.
- if `num` is an `int`, then either `num` or `num + 1` is even, ie dividing `num * (num + 1)` by 2 will result in an int. This is *not* necessarily true of `num`; therefore you should divide the product by 2, not `num`, if you want an integer result.
- in Python 2.6+, `from __future__ import division` makes `/` always return a `float` result and `//` always return an `int` result, consistent with Python 3.x

Comment: I think this answer is the most correct one, as the sum of integers should be integer as well and not a float. And it will also work properly in Python 3

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are working with `python2`, cause by default it applies integer division like other languages. Besides, you can notice this feature in this post [Integer division in python 2 and python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3).

To solve your problem you can follow the next approach:

```
def numberSum(num): 
    nim = int(num)
    return ((nim * 1.0) / 2) * (nim + 1)    

print numberSum(raw_input())
```

Comment: Thanks. So multiplying it by 1.0 allows it to divide to a float? I just changed the order like jonrsharpe said.

Comment: @user648: That is correct.  An integer times a float results in a float.

Comment: Yes, it will. As they say here [python division](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2958717/1689706), you will expect other behavior for `python3`.