# Division in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

This gives output as 0:

```
print -4/-5
```

Whereas:

```
print float(-4/-5)
```

This gives output as 0.0 . The required output is 0.8

Comment: Use python 3.It gives the right answer 0.8.

Comment: @The6thSense, it's Python 2 due to what she gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/ does integer division.

To get your desired output, the operands should be float (either or both).

```
-4.0 / -5.0 = 0.8
```

To explain the second code snippet, the first one to be evaluated is the operation `-4 / -5` which results to `0` since we did an integer division. Now what you tried to do is to convert `0` to a floating point using the function `float()`. Converting that resulted to `0.0`

Answer (score 2):

You are doing integer division instead of floating point division. It has been answered already: [Python division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division) .

Casting types after the division doesn't make sense.

```
float(4)/float(5)
```

Or simpler

```
4./5.
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

To understand,

```
print float(-4/-5)
```

Bracket is calculated first. Value given to float is 0. Typecasting 0 to 0.0

This will give the required output:

```
print float(-4)/-5
```

Comment: aren't you Sarthak Agarwal the TOPPER!?

Comment: No, same name. :) @Sanj