# Strange Python output for counter loop

Tags: python, loops, numpy, random, counter

```
import numpy as np
    from numpy.random import randn
    N = 100000
    counter = 0
    for i in randn(N):
        if i < 1 and i > -1:
            counter = counter + 1
    counter/N
```

The code resulted in an output of ZERO everytime.

I changed the 100000 to 100000.0 and it gave me the 68% but informed me  the following:

> anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:5:
>   VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an
>   integer will result in an error in the future"

Can you help me figure out what is happening?

Comment: Can you format the code?

Comment: That's because of [integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division). When you use a float, it works properly but that's not an appropriate input for randn. So either use Python 3's division (check the linked answer for importing that) or change the last line to `counter/float(N)`.

Comment: just a friendly suggestion, you could replace line n°7 with `counter +=  1`

Comment: You're not returning anything.Your indenting is strange (everything after the first line is indented one time too many), which may be causing a problem.

Comment: About *VisibleDeprecationWarning* - it shows up because the function *numpy.random.randn* does not like to receive a float parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing an integer division. Integer division means, that it will round down the result of the division, like

```
>>> print(99 / 100)
0
```

You can perform a "normal" division, by converting one (or both) of the operands to a float.

```
float(counter) / float(N)
```

The other effect that you see (the VisibleDeprecationWarning) results from `N` being an `float` in this case. The function `randn` takes an integer as parameter, not a float. See [numpy.random.randn](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html). An older version of numpy allowed using a float, but now it is deprecated. This means, that it will still work, but isn't good practice anymore.

Comment: Thank you, user :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd recommend you indent your code properly so users can run it directly to diagnose your bug. Anyway, given your snippet properly formatted:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

N = 100000
counter = 0
for i in randn(N):
    if i < 1 and i > -1:
        counter = counter + 1

print(counter, N, counter / N)
```

Problem happens when you do `counter/N` using **python 2.x**, if that's the case you need to cast to float explicitely `float(counter)/float(N)`. If you just used **python 3.x**, that float cast would be done automatically, so you wouldn't need to do it explicitely