# Dividing two very large numbers in python returns 1

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked before but the solutions does not seem to be working for me. I have two very large numbers in python (2.7) like the followings:

```
a = 332413405639482828453084501713288536462658058395850
b = 332413405639482828453084501713288536462658058395856
```

and I need the result of

```
a/b
```

As you can see the there is a very tiny difference between the two so I assume the result of this division is not 0 or 1. I have tried // as suggested in other posts but that still does not return what I am looking for. Is there a solution to this or is it something impossible to do in python or with large numbers in general?

**UPDATE**: Btw, sorry but I forgot to mention that even by importing division from future I still do not get what I want.

Thanks

Comment: It's not simply an issue of integer to floating point conversion. Not a direct duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

simple floats are not precise enough, try with the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, localcontext
>>> with localcontext() as cont:
        cont.prec=100
        Decimal(a)/Decimal(b)


Decimal('0.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999819501864298840350161830097171743383579489213731828')
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're in Python 2 land (and not Python 3) you're experiencing [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division). Try `float(a)/float(b)`

Comment: You do not need to type-cast both numerator and denomenator. Type-casting any one of these will do the trick

Comment: This is not the sole issue here. Try the same in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is impossible to achieve what You want. Precision with this big number can't be accomplished, so result would be presented as `1` in this particular case.

We can see exact value stored in float using `decimal.Decimal` (according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)):

```
In [1]: a = 332413405639482828453084501713288536462658058395850

In [2]: b = 332413405639482828453084501713288536462658058395856

In [3]: import decimal

In [4]: a1 = decimal.Decimal(a)

In [5]: b1 = decimal.Decimal(b)

In [6]: a1/b1
Out[6]: Decimal('1.000000000000000000000000000')
```

Comment: So no matter what, I will always get 1 as an answer?

Comment: No, check my comment on your main question. Use the `decimal` module.

Comment: @svens Great answer, I missed `prec` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Cast them into float first then do the division, otherwise u will get zero when the first integer is smaller than the second